# Graph stories, 3-d volumes

Tags: graphics

I saw a lesson plan that had students filling different shaped bottles at a constant rate.  The idea was to graph height vs. time to show the students how different shapes would produce different graphs,  and especially the idea that most bottles would not produce a linear height vs. time function.

Would it be possible to "design" a bottle as a 3-d shape in Mathematica, and then use integration to animate filling it...?

Comment: Yes.  The best starting point would be  the [Demonstrations site](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com).  For example, demonstrations about [fluid tanks](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=tank), [surfaces of revolution](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=surfaces%20of%20revolution), and [volumes](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=volume) are all potential sources.  There is a [conference talk](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7254/) with code to get a resolved surface from a list of points that might be useful.

Comment: @BrettChampion Your comment seems to me sufficiently complete to post as an answer.

Comment: And welcome to Mathematica.SE, Tom! Hope you'll like it here. For one moment I thought my son Tom was playing tricks with me... ;-) Please don't forget to upvote any answers that are useful to you, and if one of these questions answers your question particularly well, accept it as the final answer by checking the checkmark next to the answer. You may to wait a few days before doing that.

Comment: More or less exactly what you need can be found here : http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FillingAContainerDefinedByACurve/

Comment: Thanks to everyone , wow, that was fast... I just found that demonstration before the post was put up here...  I hadn't dug deep enough at the demonstrations site...   thanks to everyone already for the help,  It's much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  I appreciate it.   I'll try to learn some of the required procedures to be a polite member of this group.  Wow,  what an amazing amount of information!  Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 16):

**Warning: It appears that in version 9 this tends to crash the kernel.  Beware and save your work before trying!**

---

Here's a starting point.  It needs a lot more polish.

First, make a bottle:

```
{p1, p2, p3, p4} = Table[{i, 0.5}, {i, 4}];
if = Interpolation[{{0, 1/2}, p1, p2, p3, p4, {5, 1/2}}];

Column[{
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{p1, p2, p3, 
     p4}, ({p1, p2, p3, p4} = #; 
      if = Interpolation[{{0, 1/2}, p1, p2, p3, p4, {5, 1/2}}]) &], 
   Dynamic@Plot[if[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}]],
  Dynamic[
   bottle = 
    RevolutionPlot3D[{if[x], x}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
      Mesh -> None]]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then fill it and animate it:

```
volume = Derivative[-1]@FunctionInterpolation[if[x]^2, {x, 0, 5}]

Table[Rasterize@
   Show[bottle, 
    RevolutionPlot3D[{0.95 if[x], x}, {x, 0, 
      InverseFunction[volume][t]}, Mesh -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> Blue]], {t, 0.1, volume[5], 0.1}] // ListAnimate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This fails on v7 with: `RevolutionPlot3D::plln: Limiting value InverseFunction[InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,5.}},<<3>>,{Automatic}]][0.] in {x,0,(volume^(-1))[t]} is not a machine-size real number. >>` any comment on that before I start digging?

Comment: Wow,  thanks for that,  really amazing,  I learned a lot there.   I think for this to be useful to the students,  they would have to have a slider that represented time,  and be able to read the height.   The already existing demonstration is excellent, but too "built".   I'll be trying to see if I can pull it apart a bit so I can use it in a less "prepared" fashion.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: I can't make this work on MMA v. 9.0.0.0, OS X.

Comment: @Pickett works fine here, just tried it. 9.0.1 OS X.

Comment: @Pickett Yep, there were two problems which I fixed now.  They didn't always show up depending on how you edited the vase.   Unfortunately it still often crashes the kernel in v9.  Doesn't crash in v8.

Comment: @Pickett It appears that the crash is related to the Dynamic RevolutionPlot somehow.  If you delete the Dynamic expression (so it's no longer visible in the notebook), it doesn't crash any more.

Comment: Yes, now it works without errors or anything! Thanks for figuring it out, I like the code a lot.