# Generating evenly spaced points on a curve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, geometry

In the `KnotData` package a simple command such as

```
points = Table[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
```

will generate a series of points that comprise a knot (here, a trefoil, if successive points are connected).

However, the distance between points is not constant; is there a way to generate evenly spaced points? (I.e. evenly spaced arc lengths between points).

Comment: It won't be easy; the arclength function isn't the simplest thing...

Comment: `KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"]`will give you the space curve as a pure function, e.g. `{Sin[#1] + 2 Sin[2 #1], Cos[#1] - 2 Cos[2 #1], -Sin[3 #1]} &`. You should be able to at least numerically determine the arc length to get your points...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  You can consider asking future Mathematica-related questions here instead of StackOverflow.  As you can see, answers come quickly and in abundance here ;-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions!
and will do, i didn't know this existed, its very useful =]

Comment: This is (mathematically) related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2894/12

Comment: Related question: [How do I split up a curve into segments of equal length?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8970/12)

Comment: Related Wolfram Community thread: "[Computing arch length of a spline curve](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/29463)."

Answer (score 64):

I'm going to brute force it numerically.

First, let's define the function we're interested in:

```
fun = KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"]
```

Imagine that this function `fun[t]` describes the position of a moving point in time.  The the magnitude of its velocity as a function of the time `t` is

```
Sqrt[#.#] & [fun'[t]]
```

I'm going to make an interpolating function out of this to speed up and simplify the numerical  calculations:

```
v = FunctionInterpolation[Sqrt[#.#] & [fun'[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

The integral (antiderivative) of this function will give us the distance covered as a function of time.

```
dist = Derivative[-1][v]
```

This is a monotonically increasing function, so it can be inverted:

```
invdist = InverseFunction[dist]
```

Using the inverse we can generate the times at which the point passes through the equally spaced points.  Let's divide the curve into 20 equal-length segments:

```
times = Table[invdist[x], {x, 0, dist[2 Pi], dist[2 Pi]/20}]
```

Now we can easily plot the equally spaced points:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[fun[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPointPlot3D[fun /@ times, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely explained, too!

Comment: Very well done!

Comment: didn't know you could use `Derivative[-1]` for doing integrals of pure functions, nice!

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke It was essential to this solution that `Integrate` can handle interpolating functions.  `Derivative[-1]` uses `Integrate`, but as you noted it's much more convenient to use on pure functions.

Comment: In terms of points being equidistant (making evenly spaced arc lengths), what does `ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 20, MeshFunctions -> (#4 &)]` produce differently? Because I can Cases them out there.

Comment: @BoLe Feel free to post a new answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I was asking. I think now that `MeshFunctions -> (#4&)` samples points with a constant step for parameter, which don't make the desired arcs.

Comment: @BoLe You're right, I was confused for a moment too and I thought it would work, but as you say, it takes equal steps in the parameter.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Such a great way to do this, and test `EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[curve /@ points, 2, 1, 1]` shows excellent equiwiseness. Had to come back and transferred it onto my disk.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this for another spline, but it doesn't work... see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214061/manual-arclength-sampling-on-spline-differs-from-meshfunction-sampling

Answer (score 34):

Just wanted to update everyone that things are much simpler, - there is built in support for this:

```
MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}
```

So for our case:

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},

   (* the trick *)
   Mesh -> 15,
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"},

   (* styles *)
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.03]],
   MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}],

  (* the boundary split point *)      
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.03], 
    Point[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][0]]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: this certainly does make things simpler...thank you for update :)

Comment: @Vitaliy Probably you'll be interested to learn about important feature of `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` that I recently [discovered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191353/280).

Answer (score 32):

Here's one way to implement Yves's suggestion:

```
(* arclength function *)
trefarc = \[FormalS] /. First[NDSolve[
          {\[FormalS]'[t] == Norm[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"]'[t]], \[FormalS][0] == 0},
           \[FormalS], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> "Extrapolation"]]

(* length of trefoil *)
end = trefarc[2 Pi];

With[{n = 25}, (* n - number of points to generate *)
     pts = (KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][\[FormalT]] /. 
           FindRoot[trefarc[\[FormalT]] == #,
           {\[FormalT], Rescale[#, {0, end}, {0, 2 Pi}], 0, 2 Pi}]) & /@
           (end*Range[0, 1, 1/n])]

Graphics3D[{Line[pts], AbsolutePointSize[6], Point /@ pts}]
```

[image: equispaced trefoil points]

---

In case the code given above was not sufficiently transparent to readers:

1. The arclength function `trefarc` is produced through the use of *Mathematica*'s numerical differential equation solver `NDSolve[]` (thus yielding an `InterpolatingFunction[]` suitable for evaluation); recall that the function $s(t)=\int_0^t g(u)\;\mathrm du$ is the solution to the initial value problem $s^\prime(t)=g(t)$, where $g(t)$ is the norm of the derivative of your (plane or space) curve with respect to the parameter.
2. We can use `FindRoot[]` for inverting monotonically increasing functions like the arclength function $s(t)$. I used the bracketed form of `FindRoot[]`, `FindRoot[eqn, {var, start, min, max}]` to ensure that the algorithms within `FindRoot[]` do not go outside the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction[]`. For the starting point, since the arclength function looks almost like a line, I used `Rescale[]` to produce the inverse function of the line joining $(0,0)$ and $(2\pi,s(2\pi))$.

---

Taking a page from Szabolcs's code, the snippet for generating `pts` can be shortened a fair bit:

```
With[{n = 25}, 
 pts = Composition[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"], 
    InverseFunction[trefarc]] /@ (end*Range[0, 1, 1/n])]
```

This hinges on the fact that the `InterpolatingFunction[]` output by `NDSolve[]` can be inverted by `InverseFunction[]`.

Comment: I got old and slow ... beaten by 6 seconds ...

Comment: This answer thread more or less exploded ;-)

Comment: Nice answer!...

Comment: FWIW: one could have removed the `Method -> "Extrapolation"` part in the `NDSolve[]` for producing the arclength function, but I quite like using Bulirsch-Stoer myself...

Comment: a great and clear answer. thanks for the help!!

Comment: @J.M. scientific namedropping ;-)

Comment: @Yves: the name dropping makes later Google searches for stuff easier, I've found. That's why I've been shamelessly name-dropping ever since.

Answer (score 20):

Minimalist:

```
k[t_]   := KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t];
len[r_] := N@Integrate[Total[D[k[t], t]^2], {t, 0, r}];
pts[n_] := Solve[len[t1] == len[2 Pi] #/n, t1, Reals] & /@ Range[n + 1];

Graphics3D@Tube[k[t1] /. # & /@ (Flatten@pts@30), .1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

This numerical approach is based on length of chord (not arc), so it is a good approximation as long as the curve is smooth and you have close points. You have a parametric curve **f** of variable **t**. Define a numerical function that given **ti** finds such **tf** that **Norm[f[tf]-f[ti]]** stays constant. You need 2 functions to keep both negative and positive roots which will show different directions of going arond the knot and will draw knot's different halves.

```
falMax[ti_] := Max[t /. NSolve[Norm[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t] - 
        KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][ti]] == .2, t]] // Quiet

falMin[ti_] := Min[t /. NSolve[Norm[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t] - 
        KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][ti]] == .2, t]] // Quiet
```

Now the only thing you need is to nest that function - recursively feed it its own output, so it goes in even steps around the knot. Amount of nesting steps you get approximately after a few tries. You do not want to over-draw the extra steps.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Orange, Specularity[White, 20], 

   Sphere[#, .1] & /@ (KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"] /@ 
      NestList[falMax[.5], 0, 30]), 

   {Sphere[#, .1] & /@ (KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"] /@ 
       NestList[falMin[.5], 0, 30])}}], 

ParametricPlot3D[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"][t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Chord-length parametrization, as used here by Vitaliy, is a very popular method for generating almost-equispaced points when computing the arclength function is impractical. Sometimes, one also uses the *centripetal parametrization* for the purpose. See [E.T.Y. Lee's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0010-4485(89)90003-1) for more details.

Comment: Very *equi* points, indeed! I don't think one needs to worry about nesting steps. `NestWhileList[falMax, 0, #2 > #1 &, 2]`

Answer (score 14):

Here is another way to get points equally spaced by chord-length.  It will give a good result if the chord length is relatively small compared to the maximum radius of curvature along the curve. (If, say, the chord length is no greater than the maximum radius, then between successive points, the turning will be less 60 deg., and the difference between the chord and arc lengths will be less than 5%).

The method is fast because the objective function, which is the sum of the squares of the differences in the lengths of adjacent chords, is quick to be minimized (provided the initial values are ordered).  Another reason is that the speed of this particular parametrization does not vary much, which leads to excellent initial points.

The first and last point are set equal to the end points of the curve.  The code below assumes that the parametrization is periodic. The end points are assumed to be equal and one of them is discarded.

```
xFN = KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"];
nPts = 80;                                                (* number of points *)

Block[{t},
 t[1] = 0; t[nPts + 1] = 2 Pi;                            (* initialize end points *)
 sols = Array[t, nPts] /. 
   Last@FindMinimum[
     Total[Differences[Norm /@ Differences[xFN /@ Array[t, nPts + 1]]]^2], 
     Table[{t[i], (i - 1)/(nPts) 2 Pi}, {i, 2, nPts}]];   (* omit end points *)
 ]

Show[
 Graphics3D[{Red, Translate[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.08], xFN /@ sols]}],
 ParametricPlot3D[xFN[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

P.S.  If you desire relatively few points so that the chord length is greater than the radius of curvature, then generate many points and down-sample.  To get the 80 points above took slightly over 1/20 sec.  One can get 8 equally spaced points from the above calculation by using `sols[[;; ;; 10]]`:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Translate[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.08], xFN /@ sols[[;; ;; 10]]]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[xFN[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```