# How to make equidistant or split ListPoint

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

How to split the curve with more equidistant points?

```
   lpts={{1., 0., 0.}, {0.540302, 0.841471, 0.25}, {-0.416147, 0.909297, 0.5}, 
    {-0.989992, 0.14112, 0.75}, {-0.653644, -0.756802, 1.}, {0.283662, -0.958924, 1.25},   
    {0.96017, -0.279415, 1.5}, {0.753902, 0.656987, 1.75}, {-0.1455, 0.989358, 2.}, 
    {-0.91113, 0.412118, 2.25}};

   l = Line@lpts;
   Show[Graphics3D[{Blue, Thick, l}, Boxed -> False],
     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[lpts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can interpolate between the points (`Interpolation`) then use the linked answer to make the equidistant points.

Comment: Also related: [(8970)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8970), [(39394)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39394)

Comment: @BeingHuman The question "Equidistant points on a polyline" also uses points.  Have you looked at that question?  It starts with `p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];`, which is a set of 2D points.

Comment: @BeingHuman I know you have 3D, but that doesn't mean that the solutions from the linked question don't work with no or little modification.  Please do try.  If you have trouble with them, then ask.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the link, it worked.

Comment: @BeingHuman I'm happy it worked.  If you have trouble with the details of the solution, feel free to ask another question about it.