# Equidistant points on a polyline

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

Set of 2D-points connected by a polyline B-spline function:

```
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
f = BSplineFunction[p,
   SplineDegree -> 1,
   SplineClosed -> True];
```

This is neatly defined polyline function. However, as the spline parameter goes from 0 to 1 with some constant step, calculated points are somewhere denser than at other regions. (I can see the density decreases with distance between points.)

```
Graphics[{
  Point[p], Opacity[.2],
  Point[f /@ Range[0, 1, .001]]}]
```

[image]

Me I need a function that returns equidistant points for equidistant parameter values.

```
Graphics[{
  Point[p], Opacity[.2],
  Point[g /@ Range[0, 1, .001]]}]
```

[image]

Where g I constructed like this:

```
g[t_] := Evaluate[
  With[{u = With[{
       d = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[p, 2, 1, 1]},
      Accumulate[d]/Total[d]]},
   Piecewise[Table[{
      p[[i]] + (t - If[i > 1, u[[i - 1]], 0])/
         (u[[i]] - If[i > 1, u[[i - 1]], 0])*
        (p[[If[i != Length@p, i + 1, 1]]] - p[[i]]),
      t <= u[[i]]}, {i, Length@p}]]]]
```

This can be made more elegantly, right, with *Mathematica*? With some option that samples equidistant points? Because say I have some smooth curve function. I don't know how I would tackle this then. I guess one would have to integrate and findroot some.

Comment: Do you actually need the values of the points, or do you just want to connect them with nicely spaced dotted lines?

Comment: Related or duplicate? [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454)

Comment: @bills Values, yes. Otherwise Dashing? :) Vitaliy linked to an elegant solution, will study that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}]; 
f = BSplineFunction[p, SplineDegree -> 1, SplineClosed -> True];
```

A very simple approach:

```
np[u_, dt_] := u + dt/ Norm[D[f[t], t]] /. t -> u;
ListPlot[Table[f[t], {t, NestWhileList[np[#, .03] &, 0, # < 1 &]}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Testing that the points are equidistant:

```
ListLinePlot[EuclideanDistance @@@ 
          Partition[Table[f[t], {t, NestWhileList[np[#, .03] &, 0, # < 1 &]}], 2, 1],
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only small exceptions are at the original points, as expected.

**Edit**

For a higher degree interpolation:

```
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {7, 2}];
f = BSplineFunction[p, SplineDegree -> 5, SplineClosed -> True]; 
GraphicsRow@{
  ListPlot[Table[f[t], {t, NestWhileList[np[#, .003] &, 0, # < 1 &]}], AspectRatio -> 1], 
  ListLinePlot[EuclideanDistance @@@ 
               Partition[Table[f[t], {t, NestWhileList[np[#, .003] &, 0, # < 1 &]}], 2, 1], 
               AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Basic-calculus approach, clean and tiny. Thank you. The jumping around the original point parameter values isn't noticeable in my animation -- and I can decrease the step size which diminishes the jumping, and then Take only every second, third or so point since there are probably too many for my purpose.

Comment: @BoLe Yep. The idea was to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 11):

You need what is sometimes called a reparametrization by arc length.  Since the velocity is piecewise constant, it might done as follows:

```
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
f = BSplineFunction[p, SplineDegree -> 1, SplineClosed -> True];
arclengths = Accumulate[Norm /@ Subtract @@@ Partition[p, 2, 1, 1]];
totalarclength = Last[arclengths];
t = Interpolation[
      Transpose@{Prepend[arclengths, 0.], Range[0, 1, 1/Length[p]]},
      InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Graphics[{Point[p], Opacity[.2], 
  Point[(f[t[#]]) & /@ Range[0, totalarclength, totalarclength/1000]]}]
```

[image: Plot of points]

Or one could use calculus to find `t` as in the link in Vitaliy Kaurov's comment that I just noticed, or in this alternative way:

```
v[t_?NumericQ] := Norm[f'[t]];
t = NDSolveValue[{tt'[s] == 1/v[tt[s]], tt[0] == 0}, tt, {s, 0, totalarclength}];
```