# Is it Possible to change dashes into circles with Plot command?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is it possible to change the Dashed Style of a curve into circles with Plot command ?

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.005]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code ... as always

Comment: Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.005]]]

Comment: An easy way is to use ListPlot with PlotMarker. For example, ListPlot[Array[{#1, Cos[#1]} &, 200, {0., 4 Pi }], 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 10], 
 PlotRange -> All],however, it violates your demand to use Plot command.

Comment: Related, if not possible duplicates: [(8454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/121), [(8970)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8970/121), [(21993)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21993/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this approach, using [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mesh.html), [`MeshStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshStyle.html), and [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Opacity.html), will give you what you looking for.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}, Mesh -> 50, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Medium]}]
```

[image: plot.png]

#### Update

To show two curves, one as dots and the other as a normal plot, I would make two plots and combine them with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html).

```
p1 = 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}, Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Blue}];
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: show.png]

You can use `Show` to combine as many plots as you wish.

Comment: The problem is that the density isn't uniform along the curve. Any spike will give you an accumulation point

Comment: If the OP wants open circles, the post-process with `Plot[..] /. Point[pts_] :> (Circle[#, 0.05] & /@ pts)`.  Can either change aspect ratio of the plot or use `Circle[#, 0.05 {1, 1/GoldenRatio}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 As I understand it, the OP wants a circle where he has a dash. And that isn't easy (I think)

Comment: @ m_goldberg,
with the help of Plot command I want to get one curve in form if circles and other like a solid line.

Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}, 
 Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Blue}]

Answer (score 18):

If you want to roll your own solution to evenly distrubute circles along the path you could use the so called arc length parametrization of the path $p(t)=(t,\cos(t))$.  For this particular curve, it will need to be computed numerically.

```
p[t_] := {t, Cos[t]};
$Assumptions = {t > 0};
speed[t_] = Simplify[Norm[p'[t]]];
arcLength[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[speed[tau], {tau, 0, t}]
phi[s_?NumericQ] := t /. FindRoot[arcLength[t] == s, {t, 1}];
p1[s_?NumericQ] := p[phi[s]];
Graphics[Table[
  Circle[p1[s], 0.05], {s, 0, arcLength[2 Pi], arcLength[2 Pi]/30}],
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  By the way, *Mma* can solve for the arc length exactly for this particular curve (in terms of `EllipticE`), but the numerical way will handle arbitrary curves better than `Integrate`, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the `EllipticE` thing, but figured the resulting function would need to be inverted numerically anyway.  As I think of it further, perhaps the special function representation `arcLength` could be passed to `InverseFunction` or some such?  Seems overly mysteriious, though.

Comment: I think `InverseFunction` is just going to use `FindRoot` anyway.  It certainly works with `InverseFunction` and the "exact" arc length.  (Of course in graphics, even addition and multiplication are a numerical procedures, so "exact" is not as important as "accurate.")

Comment: Of course, one can use `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` these days.

Answer (score 11):

A dash of length zero is rendered as a "dot", according to the documentation for [`Dashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dashing.html).  To get a circular dot use `CapForm["Round"]`.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Dashing[{0, 0.05}], Thickness[0.02]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Curious, I am getting this http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tyhw.png . Mma 9.0.1 for Win32

Comment: @belisarius That is odd.  Works on a Mac for V7, V8.0.4, and V9.0.1.

Comment: Also fails in v7 under Windows. :-(

Comment: Fails in v.8.04 under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: There seems to be an issue amongst the various graphics drivers whether `CapForm` applies to the ends of dash segments or only the ends of the whole line. This example "fails" with v9/Windows but works if exported to pdf or eps.

Answer (score 8):

This is an alternate compute-your-own-arc-length approach, based directly on the line produced by plot, (ie not differentiating its functional form as in Mark's answer)

```
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
linepoints[plist_, n_] := Module[{arc, tlen},
  arc = Interpolation[
        Transpose@{{0}~Join~
                  Accumulate@(Norm@(Subtract @@ #) & /@ 
                       Partition[plist, 2, 1]), plist},
        InterpolationOrder -> 3];
  tlen = Last@First@First@(arc);
  Table[ arc[tlen iz / n], {iz, 0, n}]];
ListPlot[
       linepoints[
          First@(First@Cases[FullForm[ p1], Line[__], Infinity]),  25],
       PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], .025})]
```

[image]

A nice illustration comparing equal spaced points vs a more simple ListPlot[Table]] approach:

```
p1 = Plot[Cos[x^2], {x, 0, Pi}];
Show[
 {ListPlot[
     linepoints[First@(First@Cases[FullForm[ p1], Line[__], Infinity]), 
     120], PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}], .025})],
  ListPlot[Table[{x, -Cos[x^2]}, {x, 0, Pi, 2 Pi/120}], 
          PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics@Rectangle[{0, 0}], .025})]}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  One big advantage is that your approach is independent of the `AspectRatio` of the figure, while mine only works in true aspect ratio, though that shouldn't be hard to adjust. It might be work mentioning that your interpolated function `arc` has the form `arc[s]={x,y}`, where `s` is distance traveled along the arc and `{x,y}` is the resulting point, i.e. it is exactly the arc length parametrization.