# Different MeshStyle for different functions

Tags: plotting, mesh

By using `Plot` command I want to get one curve in form of circles and other like a solid line.

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
      PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}, Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit:* [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) notes that style `None` should be used instead of `Opacity[0]` because the former avoids drawing the line while the latter simply makes it invisible.  I have changed all styles in the code below accordingly.

There may be a syntax to use a different Mesh for each curve (I cannot recall) but if not you can always fall back to plotting separately and combining with `Show`:

```
Show[
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 30, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]
]
```

[image]

Two more ways to write the same thing:

```
Show[
 Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ##2] & @@@
  {{Cos, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 30, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]},
   {Sin, PlotStyle -> Red}}
]

Inner[
 Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, #2] &,
 {Cos, Sin},
 {
  {PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]},
  PlotStyle -> Red
 },
 Show
]
```

Comment: It is nice to see how many questions that one has have been already asked and solved by other people! Mathematica syntax seems quite complex to me. I appreciate this website very much!

Answer (score 1):

[Works on V7-V10, Mac OSX.] Adapting my answer to [the OP's other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39394/is-it-possible-to-change-dashes-into-circles-with-plot-command), we can use `PlotStyle` to achieve the same effect with evenly spaced dots.

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]},
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[CapForm["Round"], Dashing[{0, 0.05}], Thickness[0.02]],
               Directive[]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Caveat:** The `CapForm["Round"]` directive does not seem to be honored in Windows (at least with respect to `Dashing` in `PlotStyle`), according to a comment to my answer to the linked question.

**Side notes:**  The setting `PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0]}` in the OP's example code produces a curve, a `Line` object in fact, that cannot be seen.  The setting `PlotStyle -> None` causes `Plot` not to produce a `Line` object at all.

I've never been able to figure out how to apply different mesh specifications to different functions using one `Plot`.  I do it in the way [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) has shown.

Comment: Unfortunately your caveat is true: this does not work in v7 under Windows, though `CapForm["Round"]` works elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, bother, as Pooh says.

Comment: Nice tip regarding `PlotStyle -> None`.

Comment: "Oh, bother" I say that a lot too. :^)

Comment: This is a perfect method; it's a shame that this has not been fixed in recent versions for Windows.  I wonder if the back end graphics engine somehow doesn't support this.  Do you know which APIs are used on your platform?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm not sure I know what you're asking.  Would OpenGL be an appropriate answer?  See [Apple's overview](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/graphics-and-animation.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm asking either. :o)  Graphics used to be rendered down to PostScript (pre-v6) but I don't know what the current graphics interface, engine, or API structure is.  From past experience platform differences are often due to the system frameworks and APIs that are used.  I wonder if there is a long-term bug (or stubborn incompatibility) in the Windows back end that this failure.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know nothing relevant.  What happens with other cap forms (`"Square"` vs. `"Butt"`).  My default looks like `"Square"`, but in Windows, `CapForm["Round"]` looked like `"Butt"`.

Comment: `CapForm` appears to have no effect on `Dashing`.

Answer (score 0):

### MeshFunctions

You can use `# Boole[#2 == foo[#]] &` as the `MeshFunctions` setting to have the mesh points only on the curve of the function `foo`. For example:

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
 PlotStyle -> {None, Red},
 MeshFunctions -> {# Boole[#2 == Cos[#]] &}, Mesh -> 30, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x], Sin[x] + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300,
 PlotStyle -> {None, Red, Green},
 MeshFunctions -> {# Boole[#2 == Cos[#]] &}, 
 Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x], Sin[x] + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300,
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, None},
 MeshFunctions -> {# Boole[ #2 == Sin[#] + Cos[#]] &}, 
 Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Green]]
```

[image]

### Post-processing

```
ClearAll[postProcess, prims]
prims[x_, msh_, j_] := RotateRight[{{PointSize[Large], Point[Intersection[x, msh]]}, 
 Line[x], Line[x]}, j - 1]

postProcess[j_] :=  Module[{i = 1}, # /.  Block[{msh}, {Point[x_] :> (msh = x; {}), 
 Line[x_] :> (prims[x, msh, j][[i++]])}]] &;

plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x], Sin[x] + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 30,
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}];

 postProcess[2]@plot
```

[image]

```
 postProcess[1]@plot
```

[image]