# How to get a uniformly distributed list of points from a B-spline function

Tags: splines, plotting

I created a spline function from a list of points and made a plot as follows:

```
  list2 = {{3.93453, -0.623168}, {3.79708, -0.187231}, {3.72835, 
  0.0307369}, {3.65963, 0.248705}, {3.5909, 0.466673}, {3.52218, 
  0.684642}, {3.44186, 1.05816}, {3.36155, 1.29764}, {3.28124, 
  1.5219}, {3.20093, 1.73094}, {3.12061, 1.92474}, {3.0403, 
  2.10331}, {2.95999, 2.26666}, {2.87968, 2.41477}, {2.79937, 
  2.54766}, {2.71905, 2.66532}, {2.63874, 2.76774}, {2.55843, 
  2.85494}, {2.41254, 2.97924}, {1.98589, 3.2791}, {1.52249, 
  3.51828}, {1.27967, 3.61368}, {1.03092, 3.69235}, {0.777399, 
  3.75392}, {0.520275, 3.7981}, {0.260741, 3.82469}, {0., 3.83357}}

g = BSplineFunction[list2, 
      SplineWeights -> {50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
        50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50}]

ListPlot[Table[g[t], {t, 0, 1, 1/100}]]
```

I need my plot to have more evenly placed points.  When I take the plot out of this sample table to a larger scale plot, there are gaping holes that are too extreme for my needs. Is there any way to adjust the density of my spline function without just adding more points? Adding more points is not proving to be an effective solution.

Comment: So you want an arc-length reparametrization ...

Comment: some of this may be useful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50581/parametricplot-with-plot-markers

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39394/  The answers there may be applied to plotting `g[t]`.

Comment: @Kaisey You have asked 13 questions and accepted none of the answers.  (Are they all wrong?)  You should see a check mark you can click below the vote count.  Accepting the best correct answer is the way such answers are marked on the site and an expected way to say "thank you" to those you tried help you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry was not aware of said etiquette.

Comment: Related: [(8454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/121), [(8970)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8970/121), [(21993)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21993/121), [(39394)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39394/121)

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of at least these questions: "[ParametricPlot with plot markers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50581/280)", "[Is it Possible to change dashes into circles with Plot command?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39394/280)"

Comment: @Alexey Why not vote to close in that case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am in mixed feeling which question(s) should be closed: this thread is the only one where the general case of `AspectRatio` not being `Automatic` is considered (and in all answers!). If someone comes with another solution which takes into account the general case, this thread is the best place to post such an answer.

Comment: @Alexey Thanks for the explanation.  I did vote for your answer here, by the way. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an arc-length reparametrization in terms of a function `tfn` that maps the arclength along the B-spline curve to the parameter `t`.  It's important to use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to get the spacing even.

There are two truncation-error issues with parametrizing the full length of the curve.  One is that the stopping point is found by stepping past the end of the curve.  `BSplineFunction` does not extrapolate, so I extended its derivative in `dg`.The other is actually getting to the end of the curve.  I dealt with it by over estimating the arclength and using `WhenEvent` to stop the integration.  The `NIntegrate` used to get the total arclength is fast, so it is not very wasteful in this case.  If `NIntegate` were slower, one could overestimate the arclength in other ways, e.g. from `list2`.

The domain of `tfn` runs from 0 to the arclength.  To get even spacing, I rescaled an even division of the unit interval to the domain of `tfn`.

```
ClearAll[s, t];
(* g defined as in OP *)
dg[t_?NumericQ] := If[t - 1. <= 0, g'[t], g'[1]];
tfn = NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg[t[s]]], t[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[t[s] == 1, "StopIntegration"]},
  t, {s, 0, 1 + NIntegrate[Norm[g'[t]], {t, 0, 1}]}];

ListPlot[g /@ tfn[Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/20], {0, 1}, First@tfn["Domain"]]],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Aspect ratio**

If you want a different aspect ratio other than `Automatic`, such as the default `1/GoldenRatio`, then we have to adjust how the arclength is computed by scaling the derivative vector, e.g., by `{1, 1/GoldenRatio}`.

```
ClearAll[s, t];
(* g defined as in OP *)
dg2[t_?NumericQ] :=  If[t - 1. <= 0, g'[t], g'[1]] {1, 1/GoldenRatio};
tfn2 = NDSolveValue[{t'[s] == 1/Norm[dg2[t[s]]], t[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[t[s] == 1, "StopIntegration"]},
  t, {s, 0, 1 + NIntegrate[Norm[dg2[t]], {t, 0, 1}]}]

ListPlot[g /@ tfn2[Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/20], {0, 1}, First@tfn2["Domain"]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here is another way based on my answer to this question:

[Different MeshStyle for different functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39438/different-meshstyle-for-different-functions)

It used to not work on Windows, but I'm not sure about whether that is so for V10.

```
ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[CapForm["Round"], Dashing[{0, 0.06}], 
    Thickness[0.02]], Directive[]}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Michael, please tell me (or just vote) if you believe this question can be closed as a duplicate of one of the ones linked in my comment below it.

Comment: Pay attention that the derivative of a rational B-Spline (i.e. non-trivial weights) is wrong in Mathematica. See this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214061/manual-arclength-sampling-on-spline-differs-from-meshfunction-sampling/

Answer (score 9):

As [Ulises Cervantes Pimentel](http://community.wolfram.com/web/ulises) uncovered in [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/29463) Wolfram Community thread,

> `Plot` and `ParametricPlot`/`ParametricPlot3D` for curves can take as
>   `MeshFunctions` the values `"ArcLength"` and `"CurveLength"`.

This functionality provides straightforward solution for the plots with `AspectRatio -> Automatic`:

```
mpoints = Table[t, {t, 0, 1, 0.04}];
ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> {mpoints}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}]
```

> [image: plot]

The case of `AspectRatio` not being `Automatic` is more difficult. The actual ratio between the scales of the axes is determined by the FrontEnd and cannot be obtained without some kind of rendering. Below I show how the actual ratio can be obtained when the target `Export` format is `"PDF"`. The output is from MMa 8.0.4 but the code works also in v. 10.0.1.

First of all, I add markers to the graphics: vertical `Red` and horizontal `Green` line and replace all the colors inside of the graphics by `White`:

```
gr = ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];
grWithMarkers = 
 Show[gr /. _RGBColor | _Hue -> White, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, Green, Line@{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}]
```

> [image: plot with markers]

Now I `Export` obtained graph to PDF and `Import` it backward:

```
grData = ImportString[ExportString[grWithMarkers, "PDF"], "PDF", 
    "TextOutlines" -> False][[1, 1]];
```

In the PDF's internal coordinate system the scales along the horizontal and vertical directions are identical, hence I can easily calculate the ratio in question from the lengths of the lines:

```
xScale = Cases[grData, 
    Style[cur_, ___, RRGBColor[0., _?Positive, 0., _], ___] :> 
     EuclideanDistance @@ cur[[1, 2, 1]], Infinity][[1]];
yScale = Cases[grData, 
    Style[cur_, ___, RGBColor[_?Positive, 0., 0., _], ___] :> 
     EuclideanDistance @@ cur[[1, 2, 1]], Infinity][[1]];
ratio = yScale/xScale
```

> 0.5456134338588072`

It is not equal to the `AspectRatio` which is equal to

```
1./GoldenRatio
```

> 0.6180339887498948`

Now I obtain uniform mesh in the natural coordinate system:

```
grScaled = 
 ParametricPlot[g[t] {1, ratio}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {mpoints}, 
  MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}]
```

> [image: plot]

And apply post-processing for returning to the original coordinate system:

```
Graphics[#[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y/ratio}, 
   Options[gr]] &@grScaled
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: That's a new one! +1 I wonder if we really need yet *another* question on this topic however which IMHO only makes this fine answer harder to find.  Please tell me if you feel that this can be closed as a duplicate of one of the questions linked in my comment above.

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191353/280