# Automatically to add some points for a plot

Tags: plotting

Say I want to plot this

```
Plot[x,Sin[x],{x,0,4 Pi}]
```

And I want it to show 4 nicely spaced points, on the line.
Is there an automatic way to do this?

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364088/mathematica-how-to-obtain-data-points-plotted-by-plot-command), but it's not in Mathematica forum and I can't comment because I dont have enough reputation. One of the answer is this

```
{plot, {points}} = Reap @ Plot[Last@Sow@{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

This look like the closest thing to it, but I got this, as a return:
[image]

Probably my mistake, but should the point {x,Sin[x]} be part of the `points`? I am running MMA10.0.1 X64 on windows 7 SP1.

How do I use the points obtained there, to add onto the original plot? Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the answer from  [39394](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39394/is-it-possible-to-change-dashes-into-circles-with-plot-command)

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Mesh -> 4 , MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Mesh` works like a magic!