# Can we find a way to see how Mathematica does calculation?

Tags: monitoring

Sometimes when we have an expression to calculate, it is the kind of calculation that we do not know how to calculate by ourselves. We use *Mathematica* to calculate the expression, and *Mathematica* gives an answer, but nothing about the procedure it used. Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* give us the procedure of its calculation, rather than just an answer?

Comment: It gets a bit verbose and challenging to read but `Trace[expr]` can help here. If you search this site you will see that, depending upon your code,  `Sow` and `Reap` can also be used to make a list of the steps. For example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/automatically-to-add-some-points-for-a-plot

Comment: `Trace` can be very disapointing if you are looking to see how built-in functions such as `Sin` are evaluated. A lot of built-ins are essentially black boxes to `Trace`.