# Draw a partial line in Animate

Tags: graphics, animation

I have a list of points that my line must go through, all at varying distances from one another. I'd like to draw just a piece of this line in an Animate, where the various segments are traversed at unit speed. For example,

```
points={{0,0},{1,0},{4,4}};
Animate[Graphics[Line[func[points,time]]],{time,0,10}];
```

Ideally, the line would be drawn gradually, starting at {0,0}, heading towards {1,0}, then turning and heading towards {4,3}.  I'd like the line to do this at a speed proportionate to the distance between successive points: so for example, it takes the line 5 times as long to go from {1,0} to {4,4} (distance 5) as it does to go from {0,0} to {1,0} (distance 1).

I suppose there's the possibility of generating a bunch of "interpolating" points, but I'm hoping for something smoother.

Comment: It seems that you want an arc length reparametrization. I think there is a previous question about it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
points = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 4}, {0, 4}, {3, 0}};

interp[points_] := Module[{d},
  d = Prepend[Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences@points], 0];
  Interpolation[Transpose@{List /@ d, points}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
  ]

f = interp[points];

Animate[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, time}, 
  PlotRange -> {Min @ points[[All,1]], Max @ points[[All,2]]}],
 {time, 0, Last@Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences@points]}
 ]
```

[image: Animation]

The independent variable is taken to be the distance travelled instead of time, which is how constant velocity is achieved. Credit goes to MichaelE2 for improved interpolation.

Comment: You can also interpolate the points without separating the coordinates: Try `f = Interpolation[Transpose@{List /@ d, points}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` where `d` is as in your `Module`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice! I updated the post.

Answer (score 6):

Uniform displacement by arc-length reparametrization - Some code stolen from [@Mark McClure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39397/193)

```
points = {{0, 0}, {.5, 4}, {1, 0}, {4, 4}}
f = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
$Assumptions = {t > 0};
arcLength[t_?NumericQ]   := arcLength[t]   = NIntegrate[Norm[{1, f'[tau]}], {tau, 0, t}];
timeFromArc[s_?NumericQ] := timeFromArc[s] = t /. FindRoot[arcLength[t] == s, {t, 1}];
Animate[Plot[f[t], {t, #[[1, 1]], timeFromArc@arc}, PlotRange -> #], 
       {arc, 0., arcLength@#[[1, 2]]}] &[{Min @@ #, Max @@ #} & /@ Transpose@points]
```

[image]

It works for any `InterpolationOrder`. In fact, for any "reasonable" function. Here for `InterpolationOrder -> 3`:

[image]

Comment: ArcLength can save three or four lines of code here. Note that the lower bound should be `Min @@ points[[All,1]]` instead of 0

Comment: @Pickett I'm still on V9, so no `ArcLength[]`:(.