# Smooth animation of ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, interpolation, animation

I have a sequence of 2D-points from uniformly sampling a time dependent process and plot this sequence with `ListLinePlot`. For example:

```
data = Table[{Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/10}];
ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Epilog -> Point@data]
```

> [image]

I would like to animate the interpolated curve smoothly as a function of time. Here is what I tried:

```
i[t_] := {ListInterpolation[data[[All, 1]]][t],
  ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2]]][t]}

frames = Table[
   ListLinePlot[Join[data[[1 ;; Floor@s]], {i[s]}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 400, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-3, 1}}, 
    Frame -> True]
   ,{s, 2, 10, 0.2}];
```

> [image]

The obvious problem with this approach is that the curve warps a lot in regions of high curvature. Ideally I would like the animation to perfectly coincide with the full plot at any timestep. Any ideas?

Comment: Use path length parametrization. You should be able to search for that in this site

Comment: Example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63961/193, but there are surely more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[{x, {Sin[x], x Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/10}];
i = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
frames = Table[
   ParametricPlot[i[t], {t, 0, maxt}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 400, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-3, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
   {maxt, 0.2, Pi, 0.05}];
```

> [image: SmoothAnimation1]

---

Or

```
data = Table[{Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/10}];
i[t_] = {ListInterpolation[data[[All, 1]], InterpolationOrder -> 2][t], 
         ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2]], InterpolationOrder -> 2][t]};
idata = Table[i[s], {s, 1, 10, 0.2}];
frames = Table[
   ListLinePlot[idata[[;; s]], Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-3, 1}}, Frame -> True], 
   {s, 6, Length@idata}];
```

> [image: SmoothAnimation2]