# How can I move a dot along a line?

Tags: graphics, animation

I have a list of ordered pairs, named bob. They represent locations on a graph.

```
bob = {{8, 5}, {8, 3}, {10, 10}, {9, 8}, {1, 3}, {9, 3}, {5, 3}, {3, 7}}
```

I then created a line between all of them with this function:

```
Graphics[Line[bob]]
```

I want to have a red dot move along the line starting at {8,5} to {8,3} to ... to {3,7}.

Can anybody help?

---

My second part (which is less important, but wanted) is to do the same thing but not have the line visible. Like.. Have the red dot go from {8,5} to {8,3} and along the way, leave a trail behind.

If either (or both!) are possible, that would be incredible!

Thank You!

Comment: Add a red dot to [Draw a partial line in Animate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63959/draw-a-partial-line-in-animate)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 If[n < (m - 1), n++; tick = Not[tick]];
 Pause[pause];
 Show[
  Graphics[{
    {Red, Disk[bob[[n]], .2]}, line,
    {Red, Thick, Arrow[{bob[[n]], bob[[n + 1]]}]},
    }, Axes -> True, ImagePadding -> 5, ImageSize -> 400, 
       PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {0, 10}}],
  bobl
  ],

 Button["run", n = 0; tick = Not[tick]],
 {{pause, 1, "speed control"}, 0, 2, .1},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{n, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick},

 Initialization :>
  (
   bob = {{8, 5}, {8, 3}, {10, 10}, {9, 8}, {1, 3}, {9, 3}, {5, 3}, {3, 7}};
   m = Length[bob];
   line = {Dashed, Line[bob]};
   bobl = ListPlot[bob, PlotStyle -> Blue]
   )
 ]
```