# Line Scaled Segment or Arc length parametrization for Line

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

### Problem

I'm interested in an efficient way to render a scaled segment of a `Line[pts]`, for given `t` ( `(0,1]` ).

### 'Show some effort'

So something like `` GraphUtilities`LineScaledCoordinate `` but instead of point I'd like to draw a line from the line beginning up to that point:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

vertices = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}};

LabeledSlider[Dynamic@t]

Graphics[
  { Thick, Line@vertices
  , AbsolutePointSize@12, Blue, Dynamic[Point[LineScaledCoordinate[N@vertices, t]]]
  }
, Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

I am aware of **[Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/5478)** **but I want precise** solution. Interpolation from equally spaced points can miss original `pts`.

### Requirements

- efficient, e.g. example above for ~1k points with `LineScaledSegment` can't be laggy
- exact segment, not a fine mesh of equally spaced points, it will scale badly and miss original vertices anyway

---

This does not sound like a very hard problem but I'd like to spend time on something else, the more that I feel it is solved internally and it would be nice not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Related: [Draw a partial line in Animate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63959/731)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying Kuba's code using `Interpolation` it seems maybe (??) to work faster...

```
coord=RandomReal[10,{10^3,2}];
dist=Map[Norm,Drop[coord+-RotateLeft[coord],-1]];
total=Total@dist;
DivideBy[dist,total];
dist2=FoldList[Plus,0,dist];
ff=Interpolation[Thread@{dist2,Range@Length@dist2},InterpolationOrder->0];
fxy=Interpolation[Thread@{dist2,coord},InterpolationOrder->1];
```

then

```
LabeledSlider[Dynamic@t]

Graphics[{Line@coord, Thick, Red, 
  Line@Dynamic@Append[coord[[;; IntegerPart[ff[t]] - 1]], fxy[t]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1, old code tweak

`LineScaledCoordinate` is not `ReadProtected` so I took and changed two lines:

```
LineScaledSegment[coord_?MatrixQ, rr0_] := Module[
      {dist, dist2, sta, sto, newpos, total, rr = rr0}
    , If[SameQ[coord, {}], Return[{}]]
    ; If[Equal[Length @ coord, 1], Return[coord[[1]]]]
    ; If[Greater[rr, 1], rr = 1]
    ; If[Less[rr, 0], rr = 0]
    ; dist = Map[Norm, Drop[coord + -RotateLeft[coord], -1]]
    ; total = Total @ dist
    ; If[LessEqual[total, $MachineEpsilon], Return[coord[[1]]]]
    ; DivideBy[dist, total]
    ; dist2 = FoldList[Plus, 0, dist]
    ; Part[dist2, Length[dist2]] = 1.
    ; sto = Part[
        Flatten[
          Position[dist2, PatternTest[_, GreaterEqual[#, rr] &]]
         ]
       , 1
       ]
    ; If[Equal[sto, 1], Return[ coord[[{1, 1}]]]] (*1 -> {1,1}*)
    ; sta = sto - 1
    ; newpos = Plus[coord[[sta]]
       , Divide[
          (rr + -Part[dist2, sta]) * (Part[coord, 
         sto] + -Part[coord, sta])
         , Part[dist2, sto] + -Part[dist2, sta]
         ]
       ]
    ; Append[coord[[;; sto - 1]], newpos] (*previously just newpos*)
    ]
```

```
path2 = RandomReal[10, {10^3, 2}];

t = 0;
LabeledSlider@Dynamic@t
Graphics[{
  Line@path2, Thick, Red,
  Line@Dynamic@LineScaledSegment[path2, t]
  }, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question. As I see it, you have the arc length directly accessible because you have points with lines in between. This means the `Norm` between two points gives you the length of this section.

Here an example with increasing line lengths between the points

```
vertices = Table[{x, x*Sin[Pi x/2]}, {x, 0, 10}];
ListLinePlot[vertices]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Accumulate`, `Partition`, and `Norm`, you can create a list of the total *so-far* length in each point, where we prepend a zero at the front. Since we are not interested in the total length, we can divide this by the `Total` to get a list that starts with 0 and ends with 1 and all other values in the list represents the fraction of the "curve"-length we have already visited:

```
accum = Accumulate[#]/Total[#] &@
  Prepend[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ Partition[vertices, 2, 1] , 0]
```

Funny enough, for this discrete list, this is already our arc length parametrization and we only need to feed it into a linear interpolation, where `accum` is our s(t) in the usual sense

```
ipp = Interpolation[Transpose[{accum, vertices}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

I hope I didn't make some stupid mistake, but that be all you need

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Line[vertices],
   Blue, PointSize[0.03],
   Point[ipp[t]],
   PointSize[0.01],
   Red,
   Point@Table[ipp[tt], {tt, 0, t, .02}]
   }],
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since all you need is one linear interpolating function, this works reasonably fast even for many points.

### Appendix

As explained in the comments, you can create a function that gives you the points for drawing the lines for an arbitrary `t`. Count how many entries in `accum` are `<t`. You simply want to include those first `n` points from your vertices. The last point, which is in the middle of two vertices can be calculated using the interpolating function.

```
vertices = Table[{x, x*Sin[Pi x/2]}, {x, 0, 10}];
create[points_] := With[{
   pts = N[points], 
   accum = Accumulate[#]/Total[#] &[Prepend[Norm /@ Differences[N[points]], 0]]
  },
  With[{ip = Interpolation[Transpose[{accum, pts}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]},
   Function[t, Module[{p = pts, acc = accum},
     Which[
      t <= 0,
      p[[{1}]],
      t >= 1,
      p,
      True,
      Append[Pick[p, Negative[acc - t]], ip[t]]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Then you can use

```
f = create[vertices];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {Line[vertices],
   Red, Thick,
   Line[f[t]]
   }],
 {t, 0, 1}
]
```

Comment: But how to quickly draw the line too? Feeding tthis to ParametricPlot should probably be avoided.

Comment: @Kuba If you want to draw it to `t1`: Select from `accum` the first position `p` which is `>t1`. You simply want to include all points but the last `vertices` up to `p`. Then, you need to make one small function drawing the fraction of `vertices[[{p-1, p}]]` regarding what's left using `accum[[p]]-t1`. It comes down to render a line with `p` points. Should I give an example?

Comment: I know, it is not a rocket science but that was the question :) how to render this segment. So my point was, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: I only see the interesting parts: "Line Scaled Segment or Arc length parametrization for Line" :) 
I see if I find some minutes tonight to clear this up and provide a function for everything.

Comment: So 'segment' not a point :) arc length parametrized position is given by LineScaledCoordinate anyway. Thanks and no hurry of course.

Comment: @Kuba See my Appendix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason, it not very sync with your blue point

```
vertices = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}};

LabeledSlider[Dynamic@t]

Dynamic[Show[
  Graphics[{Thick, Line@vertices, AbsolutePointSize@12, Blue, 
    Point[LineScaledCoordinate[N@vertices, t]]}, Frame -> True], 
  ParametricPlot[
   BSplineFunction[vertices, SplineDegree -> 1][pos], {pos, 0, t}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.02], Red]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: because each segment in bsf takes 1/numberOfSegments instead of being rescaled by its length.

Comment: @Kuba So it is not your after?

Comment: nope, it is not. I need arc length parametrization