# Good way to plot exactly overlapping data

Tags: plotting

How do I visualize plots containing lines that exactly overlap in certain regions such that it is clear what lines are underneath.

This question is inspired by [Best way to plot nearly identically overlapping data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123904/best-way-to-plot-nearly-identically-overlapping-data) but with the difference that the plots exactly overlap. I thus don't want to highlight the difference I want to somehow visualize the multiple lines.

For example, for two lines the following solutions would still work

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Opacity[0.5]}]
```

But what do I do if I have more overlapping lines? Any good ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Thickness` in descending order. I'm exaggerating here, but you see the idea:

```
Plot[{0, x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness /@ {0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea, but in practice it doesn't seem to work so well. You either need a huge difference in thickness, meaning the difference between the thinnest and the thickest line looks ridiculous, or take the difference smaller but then we can't tell them apart again.

Comment: I agree, and would suggest combining this technique with others like `Opacity`, `Dashed`, etc. It's not a stand-alone solution.