# Visualization of two nearly identical datasets of 2D points

Tags: plotting, graphics, data

This question is similar to

[Best way to plot nearly identically overlapping data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123904/best-way-to-plot-nearly-identically-overlapping-data)

In my case I have two clouds of 2D points that are nearly identical. If I draw them into the same coordinate system, the second one nearly overlaps the first one. Formally this should suffice, but the image is boring. I am looking for visually appealing ways of representing the similarity and stress out the (really small) discrepancies. Should I use something like log scaling?

Added: here are specific lists of points:

```
a:={{7.13, 10.093}, {4.141, 8.783}, {2.397, 8.783}, {2.282, 
  8.782}, {2.02, 8.783}, {1.463, 8.288}, {4.267, 8.306}, {4.263, 
  8.299}, {4.124, 8.346}, {4.12, 8.334}, {3.107, 8.339}, {3.137, 
  8.331}, {2.966, 8.335}, {2.971, 8.326}, {2.678, 8.418}, {2.681, 
  8.409}, {2.749, 8.413}, {2.742, 8.422}, {4.67, 8.414}, {4.668, 
  8.426}, {4.126, 8.217}, {4.125, 8.228}, {4.364, 8.13}, {4.358, 
  8.145}, {4.333, 8.102}, {4.04, 8.125}, {2.108, 8.126}, {2.109, 
  8.119}, {1.393, 8.049}, {1.512, 8.077}, {4.249, 8.041}, {4.248, 
  8.028}, {4.252, 8.05}, {3.522, 7.971}, {3.522, 7.981}, {3.523, 
  7.962}, {3.421, 8.002}, {3.33, 7.972}, {3.328, 7.963}, {3.329, 
  7.981}, {3.244, 7.94}, {3.171, 7.94}, {1.516, 7.94}, {1.35, 
  7.935}, {1.077, 7.919}, {1.075, 7.902}, {4.111, 7.905}, {4.195, 
  7.917}, {4.198, 7.903}, {4.301, 7.907}, {4.46, 7.929}, {4.463, 
  7.92}, {7.049, 7.818}, {4.191, 7.784}, {1.904, 7.656}, {1.901, 
  7.644}, {2.098, 7.657}, {2.097, 7.643}, {2.243, 7.656}, {2.243, 
  7.644}, {4.185, 7.655}, {4.187, 7.645}, {6.778, 7.661}, {3.087, 
  7.047}, {4.238, 4.33}, {4.11, 4.301}, {1.168, 4.332}, {1.078, 
  4.302}, {0.78, 4.194}, {1.168, 4.236}, {1.461, 4.213}, {1.642, 
  4.19}, {1.599, 4.191}, {1.9, 4.18}, {1.898, 4.19}, {2.028, 
  4.249}, {2.008, 4.257}, {2.092, 4.241}, {2.283, 4.246}, {3.106, 
  4.186}, {3.09, 4.108}, {3.086, 4.097}, {3.088, 4.086}, {2.244, 
  4.182}, {2.281, 4.146}, {2.281, 4.133}, {2.399, 4.145}, {2.39, 
  4.135}, {2.383, 4.126}, {2.363, 4.11}, {2.358, 4.121}, {2.095, 
  4.182}, {2.023, 4.146}, {2.022, 4.134}, {2.104, 4.12}, {2.109, 
  4.04}, {1.395, 4.068}, {1.512, 3.995}, {1.512, 3.981}, {0.885, 
  4.04}, {1.078, 4.109}, {1.145, 4.021}, {1.145, 4.012}, {1.145, 
  4.}, {1.145, 3.99}, {1.078, 4.117}, {1.077, 4.1}, {2.163, 
  3.789}, {0.953, 3.789}, {0.954, 3.779}, {0.873, 3.789}, {0.873, 
  3.78}, {3.327, 3.526}, {3.316, 3.516}, {1.519, 3.24}, {1.52, 
  3.23}, {1.519, 3.173}, {1.52, 3.162}, {1.769, 2.941}, {1.669, 
  2.95}, {1.672, 2.94}, {1.45, 2.952}, {1.445, 2.943}, {1.317, 
  2.946}, {1.311, 2.935}, {2.347, 2.475}, {2.353, 2.485}, {2.346, 
  2.498}, {2.279, 2.419}, {2.278, 2.388}, {2.01, 2.417}, {2.014, 
  2.39}, {2.013, 2.401}, {2.103, 2.365}, {2.101, 2.347}, {2.098, 
  2.337}, {2.095, 2.321}, {2.093, 2.308}, {2.031, 2.287}, {2.026, 
  2.276}, {2.1, 2.244}, {2.1, 2.233}, {1.903, 2.244}, {1.903, 
  2.232}, {1.903, 2.256}, {1.902, 2.094}, {1.451, 2.102}, {1.45, 
  2.09}, {1.45, 2.113}, {1.468, 2.163}, {1.128, 2.164}, {1.125, 
  2.152}, {1.11, 2.114}, {1.111, 2.102}, {1.11, 2.09}, {0.885, 
  2.113}, {0.885, 2.102}, {0.885, 2.123}, {0.886, 2.093}, {0.873, 
  2.161}, {0.955, 2.169}, {0.954, 2.162}, {0.952, 2.15}, {0.87, 
  1.988}, {0.872, 1.977}, {1.521, 1.905}, {1.518, 1.897}, {1.518, 
  1.865}, {1.519, 1.881}, {0.856, 1.826}, {0.863, 1.816}, {0.853, 
  1.803}, {1.611, 1.818}, {1.611, 1.81}, {1.608, 1.802}, {0.693, 
  1.704}, {0.782, 1.632}, {0.782, 1.612}, {0.781, 1.584}, {0.781, 
  1.622}, {1.114, 1.45}, {0.782, 1.486}, {0.775, 1.498}, {0.679, 
  1.439}, {0.681, 1.451}, {0.683, 1.42}, {1.351, 1.514}, {0.861, 
  1.284}, {0.865, 1.291}, {0.866, 1.275}, {0.874, 0.949}, {2.398, 
  8.79}, {2.279, 8.79}, {2.01, 4.239}, {2.244, 4.188}, {2.243, 
  4.17}, {2.242, 4.2}, {2.101, 2.256}, {2.031, 2.26}, {2.029, 
  2.25}, {1.9, 2.101}, {1.468, 2.152}, {4.141, 8.789}, {2.021, 
  8.789}, {1.511, 8.086}}
```

```
b:={{7.127, 10.092}, {4.137, 8.785}, {2.402, 8.785}, {2.281, 
  8.785}, {2.018, 8.783}, {1.458, 8.288}, {4.264, 8.312}, {4.263, 
  8.304}, {4.121, 8.343}, {4.116, 8.33}, {3.123, 8.341}, {3.123, 
  8.328}, {2.972, 8.336}, {2.97, 8.324}, {2.675, 8.415}, {2.676, 
  8.411}, {2.747, 8.41}, {2.742, 8.416}, {4.665, 8.408}, {4.66, 
  8.418}, {4.121, 8.216}, {4.123, 8.226}, {4.359, 8.134}, {4.359, 
  8.142}, {4.332, 8.098}, {4.038, 8.123}, {2.108, 8.128}, {2.108, 
  8.122}, {1.39, 8.048}, {1.51, 8.082}, {4.247, 8.039}, {4.244, 
  8.031}, {4.248, 8.049}, {3.518, 7.97}, {3.521, 7.978}, {3.517, 
  7.959}, {3.414, 7.995}, {3.328, 7.973}, {3.328, 7.963}, {3.328, 
  7.981}, {3.241, 7.939}, {3.166, 7.941}, {1.515, 7.94}, {1.343, 
  7.94}, {1.077, 7.918}, {1.075, 7.902}, {4.108, 7.913}, {4.194, 
  7.916}, {4.195, 7.909}, {4.302, 7.91}, {4.459, 7.927}, {4.454, 
  7.914}, {7.054, 7.827}, {4.192, 7.784}, {1.901, 7.653}, {1.901, 
  7.644}, {2.097, 7.656}, {2.096, 7.642}, {2.242, 7.654}, {2.241, 
  7.643}, {4.184, 7.652}, {4.184, 7.644}, {6.777, 7.66}, {3.094, 
  7.053}, {4.235, 4.328}, {4.109, 4.302}, {1.166, 4.332}, {1.075, 
  4.302}, {0.773, 4.191}, {1.166, 4.238}, {1.458, 4.211}, {1.627, 
  4.191}, {1.601, 4.191}, {1.899, 4.182}, {1.898, 4.189}, {2.022, 
  4.244}, {2.017, 4.254}, {2.091, 4.244}, {2.29, 4.248}, {3.103, 
  4.186}, {3.096, 4.121}, {3.094, 4.11}, {3.094, 4.1}, {2.241, 
  4.182}, {2.278, 4.146}, {2.277, 4.134}, {2.398, 4.146}, {2.392, 
  4.137}, {2.384, 4.123}, {2.352, 4.112}, {2.345, 4.122}, {2.094, 
  4.182}, {2.02, 4.142}, {2.02, 4.132}, {2.102, 4.119}, {2.107, 
  4.04}, {1.392, 4.066}, {1.51, 3.994}, {1.51, 3.982}, {0.884, 
  4.04}, {1.076, 4.11}, {1.143, 4.022}, {1.144, 4.012}, {1.144, 
  4.001}, {1.143, 3.992}, {1.075, 4.119}, {1.074, 4.101}, {2.163, 
  3.784}, {0.951, 3.79}, {0.951, 3.783}, {0.871, 3.789}, {0.872, 
  3.781}, {3.328, 3.526}, {3.32, 3.519}, {1.515, 3.241}, {1.516, 
  3.232}, {1.517, 3.174}, {1.516, 3.164}, {1.754, 2.947}, {1.676, 
  2.95}, {1.67, 2.943}, {1.456, 2.952}, {1.447, 2.941}, {1.314, 
  2.95}, {1.31, 2.941}, {2.35, 2.472}, {2.35, 2.482}, {2.345, 
  2.499}, {2.278, 2.423}, {2.278, 2.391}, {2.009, 2.421}, {2.012, 
  2.393}, {2.014, 2.403}, {2.104, 2.361}, {2.099, 2.345}, {2.099, 
  2.336}, {2.094, 2.322}, {2.095, 2.31}, {2.026, 2.287}, {2.022, 
  2.277}, {2.099, 2.244}, {2.098, 2.234}, {1.9, 2.244}, {1.899, 
  2.234}, {1.902, 2.255}, {1.9, 2.095}, {1.448, 2.102}, {1.447, 
  2.092}, {1.45, 2.113}, {1.466, 2.162}, {1.126, 2.164}, {1.123, 
  2.152}, {1.107, 2.114}, {1.108, 2.102}, {1.108, 2.091}, {0.883, 
  2.113}, {0.883, 2.103}, {0.887, 2.125}, {0.883, 2.093}, {0.874, 
  2.158}, {0.95, 2.166}, {0.95, 2.16}, {0.95, 2.151}, {0.869, 
  1.987}, {0.868, 1.977}, {1.516, 1.898}, {1.514, 1.887}, {1.516, 
  1.867}, {1.512, 1.88}, {0.857, 1.826}, {0.851, 1.817}, {0.852, 
  1.8}, {1.602, 1.812}, {1.605, 1.803}, {1.604, 1.797}, {0.687, 
  1.712}, {0.78, 1.639}, {0.777, 1.609}, {0.782, 1.584}, {0.774, 
  1.631}, {1.111, 1.449}, {0.78, 1.486}, {0.782, 1.498}, {0.69, 
  1.433}, {0.68, 1.443}, {0.686, 1.425}, {1.347, 1.511}, {0.862, 
  1.272}, {0.858, 1.287}, {0.858, 1.265}, {0.872, 0.949}, {2.399, 
  8.793}, {2.28, 8.791}, {2.023, 4.238}, {2.24, 4.189}, {2.239, 
  4.174}, {2.24, 4.198}, {2.099, 2.256}, {2.028, 2.261}, {2.024, 
  2.251}, {1.9, 2.102}, {1.463, 2.151}, {4.137, 8.791}, {2.017, 
  8.79}, {1.509, 8.091}}
```

Comment: Posting your starting code and data would be very helpful. Then people would start solving your problem right away, instead wasting time on making up your code + data.

Comment: And please make it an example that has the "(really small) discrepancies" rather than just two random clouds of points.

Comment: You can add a fake 3rd dimension and use `ListPointPlot3D`

Comment: ...and is there a point-to-point correspondence between clouds or just overlapping independent random points? As was said above more details and code would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Because in your case there is:

- 1-to-1 point correspondence

  ```
    In[]:= Length/@{a,b}
    Out[]= {205,205}
  ```
- almost exact overlap which is much smaller in magnitude than points coordinates

  ```
    In[]:= MinMax[EuclideanDistance@@@Transpose[{a,b}]]
    Out[]= {0.,0.0161555}
  ```

it is probably useful to see how much are actual points apart. You can highlight that difference between points with color or size. Idea:

- Place data markers at mean position for each point-pair in a & b
- Use color or size to indicate EuclideanDistance between points
- Use proper AspectRatio to get a better sense of your data

I suggest 2 such visualizations:

#### (1)

```
ListPlot[
Style@@@Transpose[{Mean/@#,ColorData["Rainbow"]/@Rescale[EuclideanDistance@@@#]}&@Transpose[{a,b}]],
PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[.02],Opacity[.9]],
PlotLegends->Placed[BarLegend["Rainbow"],Above],
AspectRatio->Automatic,BaseStyle->15,PlotTheme->"Detailed",ImageSize->400]
```

#### (2)

```
BubbleChart[
Flatten/@Transpose[{Mean/@#,EuclideanDistance@@@#}&@Transpose[{a,b}]],
ChartStyle->Opacity[.5],AspectRatio->Automatic,PlotTheme->"Detailed",BaseStyle->15,ImageSize->400]
```

Note you can also add **Tooltip** to read out the value of differences - that is useful when points are very close to each other in clusters.

Lastly, a little observation note -- if you look only at the differences in x and y coordinates -- there is sort of a GRID-structure:

```
ListPlot[Subtract@@@Transpose[{a,b}],
PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->"Detailed",AspectRatio->Automatic,
BaseStyle->{15,Red},PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[.02],Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: I’m accepting this answer, since I’m going to use something along these lines. Otherwise i have seen some other great answers here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

One of many styling possibilities

```
 ListPlot[{a, b},
    ImageSize -> Large,
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[0.02], Lighter @ Gray], Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 simple and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

- We use the points `a` to construct a region `Point[a]`.
- We use `RegionNearest` to find the nearest points of every point of `b` to the `Point[a]` and add some arrows to show such projection.

```
reg = Point[a];
nst = RegionNearest[reg, #] & /@ b;
Legended[
 Graphics[{reg, {Thin, Gray, Arrowheads[.02], 
    Arrow[Transpose[{pts, nst}]]}, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
    Point[pts]}, {Blue, Point[nst]}}, ImageSize -> Large], 
 PointLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"start", "nearest"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It depends little bit what you want to stress. I personally like if some *quantitative information* can be obtained from the graph. Therefore I suggest a **minimalistic approach** that emphasises  large deviations.

```
th = 0.007;
rd = 0.001;
mx = Max[Table[EuclideanDistance[a[[i]], b[[i]]], {i, Length[a]}]];
ListPlot[Table[d = EuclideanDistance[a[[i]], b[[i]]];
  c = Style[0.5 (a[[i]] + b[[i]]), Opacity[d/mx, LightRed]];
  If[d > th, Callout[c, Round[d, rd]], c], {i, Length[a]}], 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

The points are placed at the midway between points from the two sets. A `Callout` is added if the distance between points exceeds some threshold (`th=0.007`). It is selected *not to overload image with information*. Furthermore, the points are minimally styled. Their color varies from `Black` (zero distance) to `LightRed` when the distance is maximal. Except `Black`, I avoid pure colors here as they are too strong in my opinion.

The majority of points should not be labelled to give the message to the two datasets are mostly indistinguishable.

Answer (score 3):

One way to show the difference is to plot vectors. Their length and color show the differencse:

```
d = Transpose[{a, a + 50 (b - a)}];
ma = Max[50 (b - a)];
leg = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 0.015}}];
Legended[
 Graphics[{Thickness[0.002], 
   Arrowheads[
    0.02], {ColorData["Rainbow"][Norm[(#[[2]] - #[[1]])/ma]], 
      Arrow[#]} & /@ d}, Frame -> True], leg]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing that maybe an animation might be helpful...

```
n = 500;
SeedRandom[12345];
data1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0], n];
data2 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 1}, {1, 2}, 0.5], n];
plots = ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-7, 7}},
     Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[#], Opacity[1 - #]},
     ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {"Data 1", "Data 2"}] & /@
   Join[Range[0, 1, 2/100], Range[98/100, 2/100, -2/100]];
Export["points.gif", plots]
```

[image]

(I haven't yet figured out why there's a "bump" in the animation.)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for presentations. However, the final presentation needs to be more static, as it will be a part of a report.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility?

```
ListPolarPlot[{a,-b},PlotStyle->PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: Polar plot of OP data]

Answer (score 2):

To see the differences between two point sets we can also use [DistanceMatrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html)

```
dmat = DistanceMatrix[a, b];
```

The default distance function of `DistanceMatrix` is `EuclideanDistance`:

```
EuclideanDistance[{u, v}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

We can visualize the distances with a variety of 2D plotting functions, f.e.

```
ReliefPlot[dmat,
 ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 FrameTicks -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{191, 1}]}]
```

[image]

The red point (lower right corner) marks the maximum distance between the first point of `a` and all points of `b`:

```
max = {First @ PositionLargest[#], Max[#]} & @ dmat[[1]]
```

{191, 11.0804}

Proof:

```
EuclideanDistance[a[[1]], b[[191]]]
```

11.0804

One can easily show an enlarged submatrix:

```
ReliefPlot[dmat[[1 ;; 50, 1 ;; 50]],
 ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 FrameTicks -> True]
```

[image]

Visualize distances of point `a[[1]]` vs `b`:

```
ListPlot[dmat[[1]],
 PlotStyle -> Gray,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[max]}]
```

[image]

There should be other useful tools to inspect point cloud relationships. Some `Classify` or `Cluster` - functions come to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting the data points over a background that highlights the differences:

```
Show[
 ListDensityPlot[
  ({Splice[Max /@ Transpose@a], 0}*# & /@ {{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,0}})~Join~ 
  MapThread[Join, {a, List /@ EuclideanDistance @@@ Thread[{a , b}]}]
  , ColorFunction -> (z |-> RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1]),  
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
 , ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Orange}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledCircle]", Black, 14], 
    Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", Orange, 8]}
    , PlotLegends -> {"A", "B"}]
 , ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]