# How to extract points from a closed curve

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset

OK, let's create a simple closed curve

```
C0 = ContourPlot[x^2/4 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];
```

and let's plot the corresponding points

```
data = C0[[1, 1]];
S0 = ListPlot[{data}]
```

[image]

Now I want to be able to create a new list, `data2` containing `N` points of the curve. These `N` points should not be random but have equal distances from each other. Any suggestions?

**Two important notes**:

**(1).** The above ellipse is just a simple scenario. The real data file corresponds to a closed curve with unknown implicit function. So, the suggested solution should not take into account the particular function. Only `data` is known.

**(2).** If we assume that `data` contains `N0` points (on our example `N0 = 200`) the solution should also work for `N > N0`.

A good starting point would be to find a solution in our example when `N = 100` and when `N = 300`, taking always into account the two above-mentioned important notes.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Using @gpap approach for `N = 100` the output is the following

[image]

Aw we can see the points are not equally spaced.

Comment: See [How do I split up a curve into chords of equal length?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/how-do-i-split-up-a-curve-into-chords-of-equal-length), [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve)

Comment: @Lou All the answers in the suggested link take into account the function of the closed curve. However in my case the function is unknown.

Comment: I was gonna say the first of the links from @Lou is more appropriate if you want the equal segments along the curve rather than each coordinate. Neither of these answers is specific to closed curves.

Comment: It may be a bit of a stretch, but this might be considered a duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/equidistant-points-on-a-polyline

Answer (score 8):

Borrowing from one of Vitaliy Kaurov's answers to [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve/84385#84385), here is a way to get `100` points.  Change the setting to `Mesh` to get a different number.

```
plot = ContourPlot[x^2/4 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> 100];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
(*
  {{-0.505748, -2.89977}, {-0.648738, -2.83537},
   ...
   {-0.0474628, -2.99777}, {-0.203681, -2.98306}
*)
```

---

Or, if the `data` is "given" -- i.e., we do not have the function from `ContourPlot` -- then interpolating the curve, as [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) does, and plotting can work:

```
sifn = Interpolation[
   MapIndexed[{#2 - 1, #1} &,
    data[[First@FindCurvePath[data]]]
    ],
   PeriodicInterpolation -> True];

plot = ParametricPlot[sifn[t], {t, 0, 200}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> 100
   ];
Cases[Normal@plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
```

Answer (score 8):

Given that a list of points might be viewed a polygonal path, my answer to [Equidistant points on a polyline](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/equidistant-points-on-a-polyline/22010#22010) may be applied here:

```
With[{loop = Append[data, First@data], n = 100},
 arclengths = Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences@loop];
 pfn = Interpolation[
   Transpose@{List /@ Rescale@Prepend[arclengths, 0.], loop}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];

 Show[
  C0, Graphics[{Red, Point[pfn@Subdivide[n - 1]]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

You can resample each list of coordinates (if you undersample with respect to the fine details of the curve, this won't work as well):

```
points=40;
newList=Transpose[ArrayResample[#, points] & /@ Transpose@data];
ListPlot@newList
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ListLinePlot`.

**---EDIT---**

Initially I thought that `#3` is just arc length but it is not the case as you pointed out. I noticed @MichaelE2 has a named mesh function `{"ArcLength"}` so this works here just as well(I am not sure it will on v9 though). You still need to add a point manually:

```
newList2=Cases[ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> points][[1]] // Normal, Point[a_] :> a, Infinity];
ListPlot@newList2
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work fine. However I use v9 of Mathematica and `ArrayResample` is not recognized. Any alternative?

Comment: the edit would work I think

Comment: See my edit for `N = 100`.  Also you use `MeshStyle -> Red` however I don't see anything in red.

Comment: Yeah, disregard the red bit, I was gonna select the red points but the I realised if I use list line plot I don't need to

Comment: Any ideas on how to produce points with equal distance with each other? I think that your approach is in the right path. Only this is left so as to approve your solution.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very inefficient way. Generate an interpolation:

```
ifunc = Interpolation@MapIndexed[{First@#2,#1}&,data]
```

Oversample the data:

```
datafine = ifunc/@Range[1,Length@data,.1];
```

Use a rather inefficient replacement rule:

```
datafiltered = datafine //. {h___List, a_List, b_List, t___List} :>
                            {h, a, t} /; Norm[a - b] < 0.1;
```

Plot with correct aspect ratio:

```
ListPlot[datafiltered, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

Comment: Where do you control the number of points?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z This is an inexact method, I'm afraid. It makes sure, that the distance between consecutive points in the resulting list is closest to `0.1` "from above", but does not offer control otherwise. It does offer roughly equal spacing. I'll see how this can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different approach. It's similar to a post that was just written, then deleted (by Michael_E2, I think). Let's get a cyclic interpolation of the data:

```
ifunc = Interpolation[({{0, Last@data}}~Join~
    MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, data]), 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
{sol} = NDSolve[g'[t] == Norm[D[fun[t], t]] && g[1] == 0, g, {t, 0, 200}];
```

This is assuming, we are dealing with a closed curve. `g` appears to be roughly linear, this is exploited in selecting the starting value in the following `FindRoot` command:

```
tvals = t /. 
   With[{n = 30, g = g /. sol}, 
    FindRoot[g[t] == #, {t, 200/g[200]*#}] & /@ 
     Range[g[200]/n, g[200], g[200]/n]] // Quiet;
```

Using this...

```
ListPlot[(ifunc /@ tvals), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was working on the answer similar to your first (at the same time as you), when I thought it was simplier to apply Vitaliy's `MeshFunctions` trick directly to the `ContourPlot`.  Then I realized that probably, the OP has only the points...

Comment: No problem, I actually borrowed the `Prepend` and `PeriodicInterpolation` from you when I got a glimpse at your post, and for sure I upvote an approach near-identical to mine :)

Comment: Near-identical was an overstatement, I concede.