# ListSurfacePlot3D generates ugly artifacts

Tags: graphics3d, splines

I have a list of $\{x,y,z\}$ pairs representing points in $R^3$. For every unique value of $z$ there are many $\{x,y\}$ pairs defining a polygon/contour in that particular $z$-plane. My dataset looks like this:

```
Take[ptv, 3]
(*{{61.52, -217.26, -80}, {63.48, -217.64, -80}, {65.43, -217.64, -80}}*)
```

These are coordinates of points residing on the $z=-80$ plane. There are other pairs for $z=-75$, $z=-70$, etc. Therefore `ptv` is of the form:

`ptv`: {{$x_1,y_1,-80$}, {$x_2,y_2,-80$}, ..., {$x_k,y_k,-80$}, ..., {$x_1,y_1,-75$}, ..., {$x_m,y_m,-75$}, ...}

My **goal** is to create a 3D surface where:

(1). the points in every $z$-plane are connected into a polygon/contour and
(2). the points in every $z$-plane are connected with their neighbors in the immediately above and below plane.

I have achieved **(1)**, via:

```
Graphics3D[{Line[ptv], Point /@ ptv}]
```

The result looks like this: 
[image: Plot1]

If I, instead, use:

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[ptv, AxesLabel -> {"x","y","z"}]
```

Then I get some ugly artifacts (edges at the boundaries of the volume) as shown here: 
[image: Plot2]

Whereas, I was expecting a more "smooth" surface without any "openings". Any hints on:

1. Whether `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` is the proper function to use (i.e. in the documentation it is mentioned that `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` may "fold" over; perhaps this is why I'm experiencing these ruffles?) or
2. What other alternatives are there to consider ?

**EDIT 1**:
Minimally working example:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ptv = Import["http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/ptvgeom/ag1", "Table"]
ListSurfacePlot3D[ptv, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

**EDIT 2**:
I excluded random $z$-planes to explore the dependence of the produced surfaces on my dataset. There is considerable visual variability in the output, including some *very* irregular images. Here is the code:

```
(* Identify the values of z-planes *)
planes = ({x, y, z} = #; z)& /@ ptv // Union;

(* Generate some random sequences with z-planes-to-be-excluded *)
excludedPlanes = Table[
    RandomSample[planes, RandomInteger@{1, 4}],
    {k, 1, 20}]] // Union // Reverse;

(* Filter data by discarding points residing on excluded planes *)
FilterData[p_] := Select[ptv,
    Function[v, And@@(Unequal[v, #]& /@ p)][Last[#]]&]

(* Generate the 3D surfaces *)
ListSurfacePlot3D[#, AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"}]& /@ FilterData/@ excludedPlanes
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

---

#### Problem

Although [Dr.belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/dr-belisarius) has given a solution, however, which lost the **geometry continuty**.

[image]

In addition, the **contour** didn't pass the interpolating points.

```
f = BSplineFunction[Most /@ t[[1]]]
Show[{ListPlot[Most /@ gb[[1]], PlotTheme -> "Classic"], 
      ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since this is my first post here, I will allow myself a question: what did I do wrong and got down-voted ? If I hover my mouse in the 'downvote' image I get a tooltip saying that the question lacks research effort, is unclear or not useful. So which one of three is it ?

Comment: You were asked above to upload your data somewhere so we can use it. By not doing so you're forcing the potential answerers to simulate a data set, which means extra effort. People here usually dislike being asked to put effort in an answer when you don't do the same in your question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand I had to upload my dataset. Is this what 'MWE' mean? I assumed all I needed was to include the 2nd code-snippet with ListSurfacePlot3D[]. Thanks belisarius!

Comment: You're welcome. MWE means "a minimal working example". Upload the minimal  dataset you can generate that shows your problem.

Comment: If you are asking about not very smooth edges, Well, the help says `attempts to reconstruct smooth surfaces defined by sets of points`  notice the word `attempts` :) I tried to find what `Method` it uses for interpolation, but could not find, other than `Automatic`. I tried few and none of them were accepted. If someone can find the `Method` that can be used there, that will be something to try. But like for many Mathematica functions, the `Method` option used seems to be a mystery item to find easily.

Comment: @belisarius your graph is spectacular! Thanks! I will study your methodology as it is very new to me. PS. For completeness / archiving reasons, I mention that this volume is a radiotherapy planning treatment volume of a lung tumor.

Comment: Could you update a new point set `ptv` owing to `ptv = Import["http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/ag1", "Table"]` failed.

Comment: Fixed, @ShutaoTANG. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The natural way to go is `BSplineFunction[]`. The problem is that it needs a rectangular array of data as input and you collected a different number of points for each z plane.

So what we will do is to get an interpolating function for each `z == const` plane and generate an equal number of points at each plane. To be somewhat more clever, we could generate [evenly spaced points along each curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8459/193), but that small modification is left as an exercise.

Please note that the Spline Degree determines if the curve pass along your points exactly, or is just a smoothed approximation.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ptv = Import["http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/ptvgeom/ag1", "Table"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]; 

gb = GatherBy[ptv, Last];
f[k_InterpolatingFunction, p_] := 
   k[p (Length @@ InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[k] - 1) + 1]
t = Append[#, First@#] & /@ 
     Transpose@ Table[{f[Interpolation[#[[All, 1]]], p], 
                       f[Interpolation[#[[All, 2]]], p], #[[1, 3]]}& /@ gb,
                      {p, 0, 1, 0.005}];
s = BSplineFunction[t];
ParametricPlot3D[s[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
                 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10]}, 
                 Axes -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For some reason I forgot about `BSplineFunction[]` and spent a good time trying to reinvent it :)

Comment: This is not fair. You are supposed to do this without using "DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`" !!

Comment: @Nasser No big deal, I'm using it only for counting the number of points at each z=constant plane. I already have them in `gb`, but using `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` seems more appropriate here

Comment: I was just kidding. I do not even know how you even did this, way over my head.

Comment: @Nasser Take a look at the initial comments. Perhaps they are clear enough to understand the code

Comment: How can we define a function s=s(u,v) considering the fact that there are different (x,y) pairs with the same z? I.e. there can't be a function z=f(x,y). Does `BSplineFunction[]` automagically take care of that by constructing s=s(u,v) as _piecewise_ combination of "subfunctions" in the appropriate "subdomains" ?

Comment: @Zet There are a lot of literature about that. You can do it both ways. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Spline_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @Dr. belisarius Thank you for this nice strategy. I tried to apply this strategy to a similar question, but I haven't succeed. Would you mind taking a look? 

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110327/generating-a-smooth-closed-surface-from-a-non-uniform-data-set-listsurfaceplot3?noredirect=1#comment299245_110327

Comment: @molkee Nope. This method isn't adequate for your sampling. Lo siento!

Answer (score 6):

The following is a laborious procedure to build an homogeneous grid with angular symmetry. Not for the faint of heart, but it matches the original points quite well:

```
ptv = Import["http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/ptvgeom/ag1",  "Table"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
gb = GatherBy[ptv, Last];
means = {1, 1, 0} # & /@ Mean /@ gb;
(*with the means subtracted the rings are almost concentric circles *)

ListPointPlot3D@(mi = MapIndexed[#1 - means[[#2[[1]]]] &, gb, {2}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Order them by angle *)
miOrd = SortBy[#, ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &] & /@ mi;
(* find a nice curved path for them *)
miM = #[[First@FindCurvePath[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]]] & /@ mi;
(* get all of them winding in the same direction *)
miMdir = If[Tr@Sign@(Subtract @@@ Partition[ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ #, 2, 1]) > 0, #, 
          Reverse@#] & /@ miM;
(* and strting at the same angle *)
miMR = RotateLeft[#, First@Ordering[#, 1, 
       ArcTan[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]] < ArcTan[#2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &]] & /@ miMdir;
(* close the curves *)
miMRP = Append[#, #[[1]]] & /@ miMR;
(* calculate the interpolations *)
interp = Map[Interpolation[#] &, Transpose /@ miMRP, {2}];

(* Now we will calculate a homogeneous grid*)
mm = Max[Length /@ Flatten[(InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates@#[[1]] & /@ interp), 1]];
Show @@ (Plot[
     ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@Through[#[x]], {x, 
      1, (Length @@ InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates@#[[1]] - 1)}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, mm}, {-Pi, Pi}}] & /@ interp)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
findAngle[angle_, fun_] := 
 x /. FindRoot[ angle == ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@Through[#[x]], {x, 1, 1, 
      Length @@ InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates@#[[1]] - 1}] &@fun
radii = Quiet@ Outer[{#1, #2, Norm[#[[1 ;; 2]]] &@
       Through[(interp[[#2]])@findAngle[#1, interp[[#2]]]]} &, 
       Range[Pi - .001, -Pi + .001, -Pi/100], Range@Length@interp, 1];

(* so, this is the grid *)
ListPlot3D[Flatten[radii, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* the cylindrical interpolation*)
g = Interpolation[Flatten[radii, 1]];

(*a scale conversion*)
conv[pt_] := {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], Rescale[pt[[3]], {-81, 25}, {1, Length@interp}]}

Show[Quiet@
  ParametricPlot3D[{# Cos@u, # Sin@u, v} &@g[u, v] + 
    Join[Through[(Interpolation /@ Transpose@means[[All, 1 ;; 2]])[
       v]], {0}], {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, 1, 22}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8], Orange, Specularity[White, 10]}, 
   Axes -> None, Mesh -> None],
 ListPointPlot3D[conv /@ ptv, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Medium]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]