# How can I make a smoothed 3D plot from a list of data?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data points that I would like to turn into a 3D Surface with adjustable degree of smoothing for readability. 
[The data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fvyt9td1i50hr3/NaDpH5260300UVVis80K.xlsx?dl=0) consist of absorption values between -0.01 and 0.01 measured at 200 equally spaced wavelengths and 12 different temperatures between 80 K and 293.2 K.

There seem to be several functions there specifically to do that, but so far I succeded with non. While `ListPlot3D` produces a nice surface but without options for smoothing, `ListSurfacePlot3D` produces some strange geometric figures

```
uri=FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Downloads", "NaDpH5260300UVVis80K.xlsx"}];
NaDpH5260300UVVis80K = Partition[Flatten[Import[uri]], 3];

ListSurfacePlot3D[NaDpH5260300UVVis80K, 
                  ColorFunction -> ThermometerColors",
                  Mesh -> False]
```

[image: plot1]

as well as `ListContourPlot3D`:

```
ListContourPlot3D[NaDpH5260300UVVis80K, 
                  ColorFunction -> ThermometerColors", 
                  Mesh -> False]
```

[image: plot2]

I have managed a smoothed surface via

```
f = Interpolation[NaDpH5260300UVVis80K, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Plot3D[ f[x, y], {x, 80, 293.}, {y, 300, 700},  
       ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"

(* 

Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently
only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All.
Order will be reduced to 1. >>

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {80.0152,300.029} lies
outside the range of data in the interpolating function. 
Extrapolation will be used. >>

*)
```

[image: plot3]

but this function can only interpolate 3D data to first order which removes too much detail.

The code used in the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30608/listsurfaceplot3d-generates-ugly-artifacts) might be what I need, but I am so far incapable of adapting it to my needs.

Comment: Here http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Fq5.jpg and here http://i.stack.imgur.com/HOloT.jpg are pictures of what I get from ListSurfacePlot3D resp. ListContourPlot3D, as I am to the forum I was not allowed to post more than two links.

Comment: You can add `InterpolationOrder -> ...` directly to `ListPlot3D`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Please leave the file on your Dropbox account for a long time, so that when people come to visit this question years from now, the data are still there.

Comment: The answer of how to interpolate/smooth unstructured data is rather involved.  I think for this data set you could use kriging...

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive edit, @ybeltukov unfortionately InterpolationOrder does not word right here as mentioned in the question.
I was also thinking of maybe interpolating the twelve series of data at specific temperatures and then use what was used in question that I mentioned in the end.

Comment: The question that does not seem to have been asked: is your data exact (interpolation is indicated, then) or noisy (in which case fitting is more appropriate)?

Comment: The data consists of UV/Vis difference spectra, with varying noise levels due to different overall absorption at different temperatures and wavelenghts. I tried ListSurfacePlot3D first as the way I understand it this should fit a surface to the data, but tried other things as I was not successful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data linked in the post is no longer available.