# Joining points into 3D surface

Tags: plotting, interpolation

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't find any questions like it here so I'm making a new one. Apologies if I missed one.

I have a list of points contained in a file which can be visualized like so:

```
data = Import["http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/782ae64cbc8003d67f4ab98d784015d6/data.csv"];
{a, b} = {data[[1 ;; 335]], data[[336 ;; -1]]};
ListPointPlot3D[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

The problem is connecting/interpolating these points into a surface, `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` yields a garbled mess for any `MaxPlotPoints`.

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[data]
```

[image: ListSurfacePlot3D of data.csv]

How can I transform this set of points into a (smooth) surface?

**Update:**

Alright fellas I'm nearly there. The best way I have come up with is to use `DelaunayMesh` with [RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine)'s code to produce concave meshes [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769). First I split the data points into non-overlapping sections by a plane between them. This is a naff hack but what can you do. Then I construct a 2D mesh for the top and bottom halves, replacing the third coordinate with `Dispatch`.

```
alphaShapes2D[points_,crit_]:=Module[{alphacriteria,del=Quiet@DelaunayMesh@points,tetras,tetcoords,tetradii,selectExternalFaces},alphacriteria[tetrahedra_,radii_,rmax_]:=Pick[tetrahedra,UnitStep@Subtract[rmax,radii],1];
selectExternalFaces[facets_]:=MeshRegion[points,facets];
If[Head[del]===EmptyRegion,del,tetras=MeshCells[del,2];
tetcoords=MeshPrimitives[del,2][[All,1]];
tetradii=Quiet@Thread[Circumsphere[tetcoords]][[All,2]];
selectExternalFaces@alphacriteria[tetras,tetradii,crit]]];

data=Standardize@Import["http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/782ae64cbc8003d67f4ab98d784015d6/data.csv"];
{a,b}={data[[1;;335]],data[[336;;-1]]};
{bot, top} = {True, False} /. GroupBy[data, Last@# < .25 First@#&];
bottri=MeshPrimitives[alphaShapes2D[bot[[All,{1,2}]],.1],2][[All,1]]/.Dispatch[#[[{1,2}]]->#&/@bot];
toptri=MeshPrimitives[alphaShapes2D[top[[All,{1,2}]],.1],2][[All,1]]/.Dispatch[#[[{1,2}]]->#&/@top];
out=Graphics3D[{Polygon/@bottri,Polygon/@toptri}]
```

[image: Joining DelaunayMesh objects]

Now I'm just missing a way to replace the missing polygons. It would have been much better to cut the data along vertices belonging to both sets. Is there a simple way you can envisage doing this?

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the points at the outset; a lot of people don't do that. If I may, where'd these points come from?

Comment: Some very messy and inelegant code. I'm looking at fixed points in random 2D vector fields. Here the data[[All,3]] axis is one coordinate of a  particular fixed point and the data[[All,{1,2}]] axes map out the domain that fixed point exists. I think Mathematica is getting tripped up by the bifurcation resulting in a fold in the surface.

Comment: do you have access to the algorithm that generated the data, or just the raw points?  It looks like its got a regular grid structure to it and if you had that grid info it would be useful.

Comment: I generated the data by first creating the boundary points, and then sampling uniformly in the data[[All,{1,2}]] plane. In principle I can generate as many points in whatever arrangement I want, although it doesn't seem to improve the result.

Comment: I added a figure from a different viewpoint to show this is a single simple smooth surface.

Comment: Related [thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30608/listsurfaceplot3d-generates-ugly-artifacts/111029#111029)

Comment: @J.M. I think this problem belongs to the **surface re-construction**. However, the data of OP is not the style like $m \times n $ array, so I cannot apply the NURBS theory to deal with it. Wha's your viewpoints about this problem?

Comment: Yes, the data is not very structured, @Shutao, so unless I'm missing any trick, NURBS does not apply here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your best bet is to generate a triangualted polygon surface. Here is an initial stab at it:

```
p2d = b[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
tri1[i_, j_] := 
 If[EvenQ[j], {{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i + 1/2, j + 1}} .05, {{i + 1/2, 
     j}, {i + 1 + 1/2, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}} .05]
tri2[i_, j_] := 
 If[EvenQ[j], {{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i + 1/2, j - 1}} .05, {{i + 1/2, 
     j}, {i + 1 + 1/2, j}, {i + 1, j - 1}} .05]
triangles = 
  Flatten[Table[ tri2[i, j], {i, -45, 35}, {j, -55, 20}], 1]~Join~
   Flatten[Table[ tri1[i, j], {i, -45, 35}, {j, -55, 20}], 1];
near = Nearest[p2d];
good = Select[triangles, 
   Total[Norm[(near[#, 1][[1]] - #)] & /@ #] < .001 &];
p3d[x_] := SortBy[b, Norm[#[[1 ;; 2]] - x] &][[1]]
sp3d = (p3d /@ #) & /@ good;
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
  Polygon /@ (Select[sp3d, Variance[#[[All, 3]]] < .0001 &])}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

At this point I havn't dealt with the boundaries or the overlapping portions of the surface, but It should get you started.

Comment: Yes, this is the kick in the arse I needed. I can actually get my bulk triangles at runtime with a little jiggery-pokery, although it won't shed much light on how to perform this procedure more generally though.

I've accepted this answer and will update the question with the full result when I get it.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure how useful will this be. Usually `Standardize-d` data is giving better results.

We can also cut off parts of the surface which are distant from our `data`.

```
rf = Nearest[Standardize@data]

sr = ListSurfacePlot3D[Standardize @ data, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Norm[{x, y, z} - rf[{x, y, z}][[1]]] < .2]
]
```

[image]

```
m = Mean @ data
sd = StandardDeviation @ data


Show[
 Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[
   First@sr,
   TranslationTransform[m]@*ScalingTransform[sd]
   ]
  ]
 ,
 ListPointPlot3D[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}  ]
 ,
 SphericalRegion -> True, BoxRatios -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the main problem for the `sr` in your answer is **smoothness**.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG don't claim it is best approach, but it is 1 line and looks way better than original approach.