# Make ParallelTable evaluate quietly

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization

```
x[t_] = Sin[t] + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[t] + Sin[2 t];
i = 
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2], {t, 0, 1}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxPoints -> 10000, MaxRecursion -> 100];
XS = 
  Quiet[
    Timing[
      ParallelTable[
        FindRoot[
          NIntegrate[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2], {t, 0, X}, 
            AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxPoints -> 10000, MaxRecursion -> 100] == i/k, 
          {X, 0}], 
        {k, 100, 1, -1}]]]
```

Even though I put `Quiet` after `ParallelTable`, it doesn't supress kernel warnings, which are present in large amounts. If I replace `ParallelTable` with `Table`, the code works, though. How can I get the same behavior from `ParallelTable`?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you were asking for, but: why not use `NDSolve[]` to evaluate your arclength function? `NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2], s[0] == 0}, s, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @J.M. because I need not arclength but points where arclength is fixed, i.e. 1/10, 2/10 and so on.

Comment: Not too hard. Using the same definitions above: `arclen = NDSolveValue[{s'[t] == Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2], s[0] == 0}, s, {t, 0, 1}]; i = arclen[1]; Table[FindRoot[arclen[X] == i/k, {X, 0}], {k, 100, 1, -1}]`. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454), BTW?

Comment: @J.M. this works well, however my concern is precision, which I can control directly when using NIntegrate. NDSolve inevitably using integration procedure, so I would avoid nesting one entity into another for no particular reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to indeed be a problem with `Quiet` and messages issued on the parallel kernels: it simply doesn't suppress them which might be a consequence of the special mechanisms necessary to forward those messages from the parallel kernels to the master in the first place.

A workaround would be to use `Off[NIntegrate::nlim]` on the parallel kernels (and probably switch it `On` after the computations are finished, of course).

Even better is to avoid the messages in the first place, which would in your example be as easy as:

```
lhs[X_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2], {t, 0, X},
  AccuracyGoal -> 8, MaxPoints -> 10000, MaxRecursion -> 100
]

XS = AbsoluteTiming[
  ParallelTable[FindRoot[lhs[X] == i/k, {X, 0}], {k, 10, 1, -1}]]
```

the trick (which is well known and described in further detail in other answers) is to avoid evaluation of the `NIntegrate` unless the argument is indeed a number. To compare runtimes for a parallel program to the sequential versions you would rather use `AbsoluteTiming` as `Timing` will only measure the cpu time on the master, which typically is nearly nothing...

Comment: Thanks. Does `TimeUsed[]` calculate this properly?

Comment: honestly, I don't know. That function is relatively new and has not made it into my consciousness and I have no experience with it. From the documentation I would guess it does not (as external processes are not covered), but that is as often not entirely clear. I would go ahead and just try with examples. If you want to get collected CPU times I think you would have to run it on every kernel and collect+sum the result...