# How can I make points equally spaced along any line?

Tags: geometry

What I am looking for is something like the output of this code:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
                 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}]
```

but I just want to have a list of the points on this line.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking a Kinked line into $(n-1)$ segments of equal Euclidean distance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214557/breaking-a-kinked-line-into-n-1-segments-of-equal-euclidean-distance)

Comment: Both of the threads linked above treat very general situations; I think it is worthwhile to consider a line segment as a very special case.

Answer (score 8):

This is easily done with `Subdivide[]` and some deft use of dot products:

```
lineSubdivide[{p1_, p2_}, n_Integer?Positive] :=
    With[{t = Subdivide[n]}, Transpose[{1 - t, t}] . {p1, p2}]

{Graphics[Point[lineSubdivide[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 10]], Axes -> True], 
 Graphics3D[Point[lineSubdivide[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 10]]]}
```

[image: subdivided lines in 2D and 3D]

Answer (score 7):

- `Subdivide`  support multiple coordinate.

```
Subdivide[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, 10]
```

[image]

- `MeshPrimitives` can get the coordinates. ( Here we do not use `MeshCoordinates` since it not always in order.)

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Line[{p1, p2}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1/5}];
MeshPrimitives[reg, 1][[;; , 1]]
```

[image]