# How can I get samples of f(x) that are roughly evenly spaced?

Tags: performance-tuning, algorithm, approximation

I am looking for an efficient way of getting 60 to 80 samples of an arbitrary f(x) such that the distance between adjacent samples are approximately equal. My first attempt is based on a first order approximation at different points.

```
f[x_]:=1-8 x^2+8 x^4;
dist=0.15;
xs=Most@NestWhileList[#+Sqrt[dist^2/(1+f'[#]^2)]&,-1.0,#<1.0&];
smpls={#,f[#]}&/@xs;
Plot[f[x],{x,-1,1},Epilog->{AbsolutePointSize@5,Red,Point[smpls]}]
```

[image: First image]

In the image above, the distance between samples is too large when my algorithm gets to a value where f'[x] is close to zero. I can get much better results with my next approach.

```
hack=2.2;
xs=Most@NestWhileList[#+Min[hack*dist^2,Sqrt[dist^2/(1+f'[#]^2)]]&,-1.0,#<1.0&];
smpls={#,f[#]}&/@xs;
Plot[f[x],{x,-1,1},Epilog->{AbsolutePointSize@5,Red,Point[smpls]}]
```

[image: Second image]

The spacing of the second samples are close enough to evenly spaced. The problem is that the value assigned to 'hack' should be adjusted for each example. Is there better way to make such samples of an arbitrary function?

Comment: What is the `distance` meaning here? `EuclideanDistance` or `ArcLength`?

Comment: Only an idea: in interpolation the choice of node points is sometimes taken with a greedy approach, i. e. for an initial selection of node points one looks where the errors, as diff between function values or a residuum integral, are the largest, and then inserts a new node point where the maximum error is. Then continue doing this until you are satisfied. Greedy applied to your problem: using your simpler method 1, and then define a maximum tolerance threshold, above which you simply insert a new point in the middle. Keep doing until there are no segments left above the threshold.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve

Comment: Same as another answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8455

Comment: The distance meaning here is EuclidianDistance. I found a very nice solution the is provided as an answer below.

Comment: Actually, distance based on ArcLength is just fine, and preferred if its faster and very robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought an implementation with equal ArcLength between samples would be slow, so I was planning to use equal EuclideanDistance instead. I came up with the code below that uses equal EclideanDistance.

```
f[x_]:=1-8 x^2+8 x^4;
dist=0.15;
nextX[f_,x1_]:=With[{y1=f[x1]},x/.FindRoot[(x1-x)^2+(y1-f[x])^2-dist^2,{x,x1,x1+dist}]];
xs=NestWhileList[nextX[f,#]&,-1,(-1<=#<=1)&];
samples={#,f@#}&/@xs;
Plot[f[x],{x,-1,1},Epilog->{Red,AbsolutePointSize@4,Point@samples},PlotLabel->"Equal EuclideanDistance"]
```

[image: equal EuclideanDistance]

The EuclideanDistance between all adjacent samples above 0.15, but it seems we should have additional samples near the local min/max of f[x]. The implementation below is based on the solution from kglr, and uses equal ArcLength. I guess I wasn't clear that the result of the algorithm should be a matrix of points. The graphics are just a way of showing what the points look like. The solution by kglr didn't include samples at each end point, and my code below compensates for that.

```
numberofsegments=60;
{xmin,xmax}={-1,1};
plt1=Plot[f@x,{x,xmin,xmax},MeshFunctions->{ArcLength},Mesh->numberofsegments-2];
coords=First@Cases[plt1,GraphicsComplex[lst_List,__]:>lst,{2,-8}];
samples=Part[coords,First@Cases[plt1,Point[lst_List]:>lst,{6,-3}]];
samples=SortBy[Join[{{xmin,f@xmin},{xmax,f@xmax}},samples],First];
Plot[f[x],{x,xmin,xmax},Prolog->{AbsolutePointSize@4,Red,Point@samples},PlotLabel->"Equal ArcLength"]
```

[image: equal ArcLength]

Both solutions above are fairly fast, but the second approach meets my needs much better.

Answer (score 14):

```
f[x_] := 1 - 8  x^2 + 8  x^4;
```

You can use the option `MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}` and ...

#### 1.

**Specify the number of equal-arc-length segments**

```
numberofsegments = 60;

mesh1 = numberofsegments - 1;

plt1 = Plot[f @ x, {x, -1, 1},
  MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, 
  Mesh -> mesh1, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize @ Medium, Red], 
  MeshShading -> {Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

**Verify that we get 60 equal-arc-length line segments:**

```
{Length @ #, Counts @ N @ Round[#, 10^-3]} & @
 Cases[plt1, l : Line[{__List}] :> ArcLength @ l, All]
```

> ```
> {60, <|0.14 -> 60|>}
> ```

#### 2.

**Specify segment length**

```
dist = 0.15;

al = N @ ArcLength[f[x], {x, -1, 1}];

mesh2 = {Range[0, al, dist]/al};

plt2 = Plot[f @ x, {x, -1, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, 
  Mesh -> mesh2, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize @ Medium, Red], 
  MeshShading -> {Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

**Verify that all line segments (except the last one) has arc length `dist`:**

```
{Length @ #, Counts @ N @ Round[#, 10^-3]} & @
 Cases[plt2, l : Line[{__List}] :> ArcLength @ l, All]
```

> ```
> {57, <|0.15 -> 56, 0.029 -> 1|>}
> ```

Answer (score 13):

- If we want to the `ArcLength` approximately equal to the `dist = 0.15;`, we can define an arclength function `arclength` which satisfies the differential equation `arclength'[x] == Sqrt[1 + D[f[x], x]^2]`.

```
Clear[f, dist, sol, times];
f[x_] := 1 - 8  x^2 + 8  x^4;
dist = 0.15;
{sol, times} = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == D[f[x], x], y[-1] == f[-1], 
     arclength'[x] == Sqrt[1 + D[f[x], x]^2], arclength[-1] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[Mod[arclength[x], dist] == 0, Sow[x]]}, {y, 
     arclength}, {x, -1, 1}] // Reap;
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, -1, 1}, Mesh -> times, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 MeshShading -> {Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 1 - 8  x^2 + 8  x^4;

dist = 0.15;

length = ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}] // N

(* 8.42921 *)
```

The following calculation is quite slow

```
xval[len_?NumericQ] := xv /. FindRoot[
   ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, xv}] == len, {xv, 
    Rescale[len, {0, length}, {-1, 1}]}]

xvalues = Prepend[xval /@ Range[dist, length, dist], -1];

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1},
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red,
   Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ xvalues]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- To contain the boundary points, we can use `MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"}` and `Subdivide[numberofsegments]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := 1 - 8  x^2 + 8  x^4;
numberofsegments = 60;
{xmin, xmax} = {-1, 1};
plt1 = Plot[f@x, {x, xmin, xmax}, MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"},
   Mesh -> {Subdivide[numberofsegments]}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]